# Shortcut for %paste function

Tags: python, ipython, paste

Is there any way to set up ipython so whenever you trigger a short cut it will automatically run the magic function %paste or %cpaste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new IPython version does not require magic commands to paste. You can just press ctrl+v to paste.

It is an easy update using pip.

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
```

For more information, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419584/6203717) out, and [here](http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/07/08/ipython-5-0-released/)