# PyShell and IPython are showing an extra indentation that is not there

Tags: python, vim, tmux, slime

I just started using tmux along with slime, PyShell and IPython and I have ran into the following problem.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
nc = { name : 0 for name in names}
count = 1
for name in names:
    nc[name] += count
    count += 1
print(nc)
```

and when I normally run the file in terminal using `python3 file.py`, it correctly returns `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`.

However, when running this with slime, it is saying that there is an unexpected indent and the error message is showing that the following is being inputted:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
nc = { name : 0 for name in names}
count = 1
for name in names:
    nc[name] += count
        count += 1
print
```

However, this is not what I am inputting. Here is a [image: screen shot] to show this. Where is the problem coming from?

Comment: Does it work if you try the `%autoindent` command to toggle off automatically adding indentation and then paste the code? Or you can try `%cpaste` or `%paste` . [How does IPython's magic %paste work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886946/how-does-ipythons-magic-paste-work).

Comment: @NathanMills that did work but I have not been able to find away to set no autoindent as the default. Each time I open IPython I need to reenter `%autoindent`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by IPython inserting an indent automatically. To turn off automatic indent, use `%autoindent` command in IPython. To keep the option off when you restart IPython, add the line

```py
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.autoindent=False
```

to your **ipython_config.py** which is located in a profile_*profilename* folder under the `~/.ipython` directory on Linux. The default config would be located at `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`. If you don't already have a config file, run

```
ipython profile create default
```

to create a default profile or name it something else by replacing `default` in above command with the desired profile name.

Comment: Thank you, I thought my ipython had broken down because I could no longer copy in functions with indentations. However, with you fix I have a new problem. After applying %autoindent I cannot copy functions into ipython, because it will execute every single line by itself, instead of letting me paste a block of multiple lines. Things worked great until just a few weeks ago. What has changed recently in ipython and how can I get back the normal behavior? I always develop code in vim and then copy blocks of code into ipython to run it...

Answer (score 0):

The interactive shell you're using isn't made for use with pasted code.
It tries to be helpful and indents lines to where it thinks you want them to be indented

To illustrate I'll mark leading spaces provided by the repl with '.' and spaces you pasted with ';'

```py
for name in names:
....;;;;count += 1
........;;;;nc[name] += count
```

So the problem is the repl trying to assist you. Try to find out a way to either load python code into your repl or to enable a "paste" mode where it will not try to guess an indentation level for you.