# SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-idle, python-3.3

I'm in Python 3.3 and I'm only entering these 3 lines:

```
import sklearn as sk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

What could I be doing wrong?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 62):

I had the same problem. This worked for me on mac (and linux):

```
echo "set enable-bracketed-paste off" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Comment: For macOS, this is the correct answer. Just add that and restart the python console and it will now accept pasting multiple lines.

Comment: did not work for me on iterm

Comment: See this homebrew issue for more details: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/68193

Comment: I am on Ubuntu Linux and it worked for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

In the shell, you can't execute more than one statement at a time:

```
>>> x = 5
y = 6
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

You need to execute them one by one:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 6
>>>
```

When you see multiple statements are being declared, that means you're seeing a script, which will be executed later. But in the interactive interpreter, you can't do more than one statement at a time.

Comment: This is not true, you can just paste in `x=6 \n x=6` and it will work just fine. Its impossible to say without a full traceback, and I think the actual answer is more towards jmu's

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Hum.. Really? I pasted your snippet and i got `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`..

Comment: I pasted his code into the console, and got no error whatsoever.

Comment: @Games What are you using? I pasted it and i got exactly the same error with the one in my answer.

Comment: I believe GB means `\n` as in an actual newline. aIKid, are you pasting a literal backslash and n?

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, yeah, i did. But using an actual newline just got me the same error as in my answer.

Comment: Let's just continue in chat, meanwhile i'll delete this answer.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac You're still here?

Comment: @aIKid mmhmm. I think we need to see a full traceback before we can actually give a definitive answer.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Yeah, sure, but can you join me in chat?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac False. Using the shell you cannot enter multiple statements using Enter or \n. You can enter multiple statements by separating the statements using semicolon, as in  `x = 5; y = 6` . You need to go into script mode.

Answer (score 7):

A (partial) practical work-around is to put things into a throw-away function.

Pasting

```
x = 1
x += 1
print(x)
```

results in

```
>>> x = 1
x += 1
print(x)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x += 1
print(x)

    ^
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
>>>
```

However, pasting

```
def abc():
  x = 1
  x += 1
  print(x)
```

works:

```
>>> def abc():
  x = 1
  x += 1
  print(x)
>>> abc()
2
>>>
```

Of course, this is OK for a quick one-off, won't work for everything you might want to do, etc. But then, going to `ipython` / `jupyter qtconsole` is probably the next simplest option.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the interactive shell which allows on line at a time. What you can do is put a semi-colon between every line, like this -
`import sklearn as sk;import numpy as np;import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.
Or you can create a new file by control+n where you will get the normal idle. Don't forget to save that file before running. To save - control+s. And then run it from the above menu bar - run > run module.

Answer (score 1):

Long-term solution is to just use another GUI for running Python e.g. IDLE or `M-x run-python` in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to download Idlex and use its IDLE version, which allows multiple lines.

---

<sub>This was originally added to [Revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21226808/4) of the question.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I am on windows executing python code through wsl.
What worked for me is switching to Jupyter Notebook. It's easy to get with `pip install jupyter`; then deploy with `jupyter notebook`.
It allows pasting multiple lines into each 'cell' as well as plenty more functionality:
[image: using Jupyter Notebook]