# Syntax error ; multiple statements found while

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is there this syntax error 'Multiple statements found while compiling a single statement' given when I run this code? Answer and help will be super appreciated for this python newbie here
[image: Error]

Comment: where is the code ? share the code please. @James Davies

Comment: How are you even able to write so many instruction in terminal? I tried to mimic but as I tried to hit enter it executes the command.

Answer (score -1):

A quick look at google found me this:

[SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226808/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement)

Just dont add multiple statements into a python-idle line.
Write a .py-file and then execute it.