# Why SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement in Python IDE?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

wine_dict = {
    'red_wine': [3, 6, 5],
    'white_wine':[5, 0, 10]
}
sales = pd.DataFrame(wine_dict, index=["adam", "bob", "charles"])
print(sales)
```

Please help me to run the code in my IDE.

Comment: Unindent your code.  `import` should be at the very beginning of the line, not indented four spaces.

Comment: Indentation issues should not produce "multiple statements" error. There are a plenty of questions on SO with the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226808/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement, and I believe this code is executed via shell, which tries to execute the whole block as a single statement. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262109/syntax-error-multiple-statements-found-while) includes a good image of what is possibly happening here

Comment: How are you running this code? Are you really using an IDE. If so which one? Or do you mean Python IDLE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226808/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement)

Answer (score 2):

The code you have pasted contains indented statements. [Indents](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) have a meaning in Python.

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

[image: Code output]

Your code works fine after removing all the indents.

Edit:

#### Your code after removing indents:

```
import pandas as pd

wine_dict = {
    'red_wine': [3, 6, 5],
    'white_wine':[5, 0, 10]
    }
sales = pd.DataFrame(wine_dict, index=["adam", "bob", "Charles"])
print(sales)
```

Comment: Can you please paste my code again removing all the indents..

Comment: I don't think you can assume this, that could be just the way it got pasted into SO. Lots of people add extra indentation when posting.

Comment: @junayeD added the correct code, please take a look at it.

Comment: @MihirJoshi bro I run the code in my Python IDE but don't know why the error message is still seeing. I take a screenshot of my IDE after running the code with indents. I can't add image in the comment section. Check it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10_XIcCk9UWTXdhjoT0QYaurIM1-62Qq5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @junayeD the file is private, I requested access. If you can't add an image in the comment section, you can share the imgur link as well (it's public, unlike GDrive).

Answer (score 1):

you are running code in idle itself. go to new file paste the code and then run it.

I hope it works.

Comment: I run the code in my Python IDE but don't know why the error message is still seeing. I take a screenshot of my IDE after running the code with indents. I can't add image in the comment section. Check it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10_XIcCk9UWTXdhjoT0QYaurIM1-62Qq5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @junayeD Need to see the screenshot