# Print files over 1GB

Tags: python

I am learning how to write python. As a test I want to print the names of all files bigger than 1GB here is my code so far:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\brentond\\Documents\\Outlook Files'
for filename in path:
    if os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, filename))>1000000000:
        print(filename)
```

I get this error

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

Comment: `filename` here is each character of the string `path`

Comment: Also, from [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21226808/1639625) it seems like you pasted this into an interactive shell instead of creating and running a `.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ypur case, path is just a string, and looping through it will return each character. you have to use `os.listdir()` to get a list.

Also, you could test for file first, so you don't get size for evry directory as well.

here is the full code

```py
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename)) and os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, filename))>1000000000:
        print(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `path` with `os.listdir()` which will return an iterable of files in your path.

```
for filename in os.listdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use os.listdir instead:

```
 import os
 for filename in os.listdir(path):
```

and then the rest of your code