# How can I write multi-line code at the Python REPL (in a terminal window)?

Tags: python, terminal

Suppose I run Python from a terminal window and get the REPL prompt:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:~ ldl$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I want to input some code like:

```
i = 0

while i < 10:
    i += 1
    print i
```

How do I actually type the newlines and indent the code?

I tried using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>; none of them worked. The code does not indent:

```
>>> while i < 10:
... print i 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print i 
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: It is invalid syntax, so it won't continue to prompt you to write next line.

Comment: `for` should be `while`.

Comment: Why are you not writing in code the examples you previously wrote?

Comment: @zhenguoli sorry about the typo, now I modified it.

Comment: I don't believe you can with the REPL. An easy alternative that is more user friendly would be Jupyter Notebook. Can be easily installed with `pip` and started with `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Related: [Copying and pasting code directly into the Python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501208). If this question gets really properly answered, the other one might be better closed as a duplicate of this (since it broadens the scope only slightly, but still coherently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the code and past it in the terminal, and press return. This code works perfect if you do that:

```
   i = 0 
..  
.. while i < 10: 
..     i += 1 
..     print(i)  
..   

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: This won't work if there's a blank line *inside* the while-loop block, or any other indented block.

Answer (score 15):

You can add a trailing backslash. For example, if I want to print a 1:

```
>>> print 1
1
>>> print \
... 1
1
>>>
```

If you write a \, Python will prompt you with ... (continuation lines) to enter code in the next line, so to say.

To resolve `IndentationError: expected an indented block`, put the next line after while loop in an indented block (press Tab key).

So, the following works:

```
>>> i=0
>>> while i < 10:
...   i+=1
...   print i
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: The indent also works as expected when the syntax is correct.

Comment: This one worked for me. I needed a solution working just in the command line, and not copy/pasting from a text editor.

Comment: It only works up to one extra line. In the second line, if I press Enter or Shift+Enter, I get a syntax error. Indentation or not, makes no difference.

Comment: @Unknow0059 typing a blank line signals to the REPL that the block has ended, and you get a syntax error because the block is empty (Python requires something inside each block to avoid accidents). I'm currently offering a bounty to explain the whole system properly.

Answer (score 4):

There comes out:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

So, when use the while loop, the next line should have the indented block(press Tab key).

```
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < 10:
...     i += 1
...     print i 
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the `python3 - <<'EOF'` command.

For instance:

```
python3 - <<'EOF'
a=7
b=5
print(a+b)
EOF
```

> 12

Comment: This is a way to execute the code, but it isn't quite "at the REPL", and doesn't offer much advantage over just putting the code in a `.py` file first.

Answer (score 1):

Python automatically detects code blocks in sections like for-next, while, etc. Just put a ':' <-- Colon symbol after some code.

Then the next line will have a continuation symbol ('...') in front of it instead of the prompt ('>>>')

Remember to press a tab to indent the code that you want to execute in the block. That will indent the line and tell Python that the code that follows is a part of the block.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a little late, but you can try this

```bash
$: echo "\
i = 0

while i < 10:
    i += 1
    print i 
" | python3
```

Comment: This is functionally the same as anshul singh's suggestion - one might as well just create a `.py` file at this point. The other syntax is also probably easier to work with overall - although this makes it even more obvious that we're relying on the shell itself rather than just Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can just paste the code. However, if the pasted code contains empty lines, it may fail. For example, pasting the following causes an infinite loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(i)

    i += 1
```

That's because the standard REPL starts running the code as soon as it encounters a blank line, which it treats as a signal that the code has ended. So in the example above, it will never read the increment.

There are some workarounds, but no guaranteed way to do this. You can run the pasted code into `exec`, but it will fail if the pasted code contains a triple-quoted string:

```
exec("""i = 0

while i < 10:
    print(i)

    i += 1""")
```

If you don't want to rely on `exec`, then you will need to change the code you are pasting. Either remove the blank lines or replace  them with indentation or a single space.

```
i = 0

while i < 10:
    print(i)
 # this comment not needed; this is only here 
 # to emphasize that this line is not really empty
    j = 0
    while j < 2:
        print(i, j)
 #
        j += 1
 #
    i += 1
```

The silver lining is that you can easily do this in an editor that allows you to replace empty lines with a space.

Another trick is to make every line start with some indentation and then add a dummy `if` at the beginning:

```
if True:
    i = 0
    #
    while i < 10:
        print(i)
    # 
        i += 1
```

But again, there's no sure way to just copy and paste into REPL without some work. If that's a deal-breaker, then it's best to just use IPython.