Python code runs fine in VScode, but not in terminal - adds indentation
I just installed VSCode on my laptop. Every time I want to test a function in the terminal (shift+enter), it throws me an indentation error. I have tried everything in indentation settings, and have ensure indentation is always 4 spaces.
For example, the code below runs fine in the interactive window or in debugging.
def test():
    x = 3
    y = 4
    return x + y

But when I select those lines and press SHIFT+ENTER, I get an unexpected indentation error.
>>> def test():
...             x = 3
...                 y = 4
...                     return x + y
... 
  File "<python-input-1>", line 3
    y = 4
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Indeed, even if I paste existing code from elsewhere into the terminal, it somehow adds indent on every new line, causing indentation errors as well. Interestingly, I don't get this error when I type my code directly into the terminal.
The combination of everything I tried (disabling all extensions, modifying autoindent settings, uniform indentations, etc.) and the simple examples I have been using - both sent from the editor and copied from other code - I am convinced it has to do with something in the python terminal that I'm missing. Is there a reason why it would add multiple tabs or spaces in front of every new line that is pasted in the terminal?
I am running:

Python 3.13.0
VSCode 1.94.2
Windows 11 Home
CRLF line ending

I currently only have the following extension installed:

Python
Pylance
Jupyter


What version of python are you running? I think this is fixed in later versions (eg 3.10). Try entering exec(''' at the prompt, then paste your code and then '''). That's a workaround I used to use.

This may be relevant; apparently solved in 2023.8.31

use tabs by default for indenting

Preliminary bug report: Python3.13 All functions fail to send: IndentationError: unexpected indent

@sahasrara62 Why tabs? PEP 8 recommends 4 spaces. Do you want to expand on that in an answer?

@wjandrea tabs works better when u copy from ide to temrinal

what platform are you on? what line endings is this file using? (please edit this info into your question post) I suspect a line ending problem.

thanks for the suggestion @starball
changing the line endings had no effect, and the terminal also inserts additional indentation when I copy code from other sources

if you want to copy and paste code into the REPL just use IPython as the REPL, not the default one that comes with Python

Would you mind copying the code to a terminal text editor and see if it will indent like this?Also there seems to be a similar question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501208/copying-and-pasting-code-directly-into-the-python-interpreter maybe you could take a look.

I had similar issue from Visual Studio Code does not print to terminal with correct indentation
solved by reverting to python 3.12, no indentation issues after that

