# How do I make variable values to be saved after running a Python script in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging

After the Python script execution I want to play with the variables which I generated during the execution.

Like, for example, one can do in RStudio, or the standard Python interpreter console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the most straightforward option is to use the Python shell to simply `import` the file where the variable definitions are stored.

For example, foo.py would be:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Then in the python shell running in the same directory:

```
>>> import foo # or, from foo import *
>>> foo.a
1
>>> foo.b
2
>>> foo.a + foo.b
3
```

If you import everything, you can use any functions/classes/etc. interactively as well.

Comment: If I want to do it from PyCharm console, my file should be contained i the Console 'Working directory'. How do I change that directory?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyCharm. Apparently all files in the current project are added to the path, so you can just import? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329601/interactive-shell-debugging-with-pycharm