# Can I simply run the sum of two numbers on Pycharm without assigning it a variable first?

Tags: python, pycharm

Why is it that I can simply run the sum of two numbers in Python's IDLE, but cannot do the same in Pycharm without assigning it a variable?

Running the sum 1 + 1 on Pycharm produces nothing without assigning it a variable and then printing it. I was able to do this easily in the IDLE I received from my Python installation. Why is this so? I'm inexperienced with Python and programming in general. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Probably useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329601/interactive-shell-debugging-with-pycharm

Comment: In an interactive session, the input is read, evaluated and then printed. When you write 1+1 into a file, and then run python, the result is computed and then discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the PyCharm console. If you just write `1 + 1` to a file, it *shouldn't* be doing anything. Just go to Tools > Python Console.

[image]