# Pycharm: different behavior between run and run in Python console?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm on Pycharm with python3. 
I can run the code by shift+control+R (short cut for run, equivalent to press the green triangle run button)
Or
run the code by shift+alt+E to load the code into Python console suggested by [interactive shell debugging with pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329601/interactive-shell-debugging-with-pycharm)

shift+control+R gives no errors.

shift+alt+E throws an exception:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

The code I run as follows:

```
import sys

sys.exit('exist')

print('shouldnt print')
```

I want to understand what causes the different behavior and how I can avoid this. The code is inline with `sys.exit` documentation for python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Shift + Alt + E is pressed, it enters the Interactive shell. `sys.exit()` doesn't work for IDLE applications such as the Interactive shell. For IDLE applications, the built-in `os._exit()` is used instead.

When you closely examine the stack trace, you will notice this behavior:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 260, in DoExit 
    os._exit(args[0])

TypeError: an integer is required
```

`os._exit()` is executed (instead of `sys.exit("exist")`), and it takes only an integer as an argument. Check the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit

Comment: How may I know what works for IDLE applications and what doesn't? I encountered similar issue when filter a list.

Comment: @Lisa, I am not sure if there are other exceptions. But if you post the problem on SO, maybe someone can take a look and answer.