# Rerun python program from terminal after making changes

Tags: python, command-line

It is very nice and easy to run Python from the command line. Especially for testing purposes. 
The only drawback is that after making a change in the script, I have to restart Python, do all the imports over again, create the objects and enter the parameters.

```
$ python
>>> from foo import bar
>>> from package.file import Class
>>> c = Class
>>> c.name = "John"
>>> c.age = 33
>>> c.function()
>>> from datetime import timedelta, datetime
>>> now = datetime.now().year()
>>> next_year = now + timedelta(year=1)
>>> etc...
```

Can someone tell me if there is an easier way then doing all the work over and over again every time I make a change in the Python code?

Comment: It would help if you were clearer about what you're trying to do after changing the script. Are you testing functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I watch a file for changes using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider turning your testing into an actual python script. which can be run like this, and then checking the output

```
$ python my_tests.py
```

However, a much better way would be to write some unit tests which you can run in a similar way. https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html. The unittest framework will run all the tests you've defined and gather the results into a report.

If you need some steps to be done interactively, then you can achieve that by writing your setup into a script, and then executing the script before doing your interactive tests. See this other SO question: [Is there a possibility to execute a Python script while being in interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624416/is-there-a-posibility-to-execute-a-python-script-while-being-in-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Use IPython with a [notebook](http://jupyter.org/) instead. Much better for interactive computing.

Answer (score 0):

Going for IPython as well. You can write a script which will enter an interactive shell at any point in any frame, for example:

```
import IPython
from foo import bar
from package.file import Class
c = Class
c.name = "John"
c.age = 33
c.function()
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
now = datetime.now().year()
next_year = now + timedelta(year=1)
IPython.embed()
```

Then simply run your script with python, and you'll get an interactive shell at the end.