# setuptools error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

i am new to python and i am installing python pakages but i get this error

```
Error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 3 in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, find_packages
    ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

but when iam installing setuptools and run it i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/yyy.py", line 7, in <module>
    execfile(convert_path('setuptools/command/__init__.py'), d)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

i am windows 7 user . if any 1 have experience about it please figure it out
 and whats this mean
Unpack the archive, enter the pyserial-x.y directory and run ? mean i have to install it from command prompt

i want to use twitter api in python . when i run its setup file it show error . i open it with notepad and copy the setup code and paste it in script and save it with yyy.py and run it and now it give me the error like this

```
File "C:\Python26\twittersetup.py",
line 13, in <module> 
long_description=open("./README", "r").read(), 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './README'
```

this errorr in python 3.2

```
File "C:/Python32/t.py",
line 9, in <module> 
setup(name='twitter',
NameError: name 'setup' is not defined
```

AND NOW AFTER MANY SURVIVALS I GOT THIS ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sheikh\Desktop\twitter-1.9.0 (1).tar\twitter-1.9.0\setup.py",
line 47, 
in <module>""",File "C:\Python32\lib\distutils\core.py",
line 136, in setup
raise SystemExit(gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg)
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help
error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Can you include the code from the `yyy.py` file above?  You have an error installing a package and then another error trying to install setuptools to allow you to install the package?

Comment: this errorr in python 3.2                        (((File "C:/Python32/t.py", line 9, in <module>
    setup(name='twitter',
NameError: name 'setup' is not defined)))))

Comment: you can edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Why are you copying and pasting the `setup.py` into a separate file?   You can't run the setup script from anywhere but the `python-twitter` source directory.

Comment: i hope this is now readable for you . and i wish it also understandable for you :)

Comment: if i run it from there it also give the error . black screen flash for sometime and thn gone and nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to install setuptools from pypi and then you need to run setup.py file through commands using cmd. Using setup.py --help-commands in Windows tell you the step and commands.

Answer (score 2):

`execfile()` will only work in Python 2, use `exec()` in Python 3

From http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/ it is clear that `setuptools` is only available for python `2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7`, so better install it on one of them not on 3.x.

Read [Alternative to `execfile` in Python 3.2+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357361/alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-2)

---

**Edit:** Setuptools now support Python 3.3+.

Answer (score 2):

`setuptools` doesn't appear to support python 3 (at least according to the Python Package Index).

Try `distribute` which provides the `setuptools` api and provides python3 compatibility: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute

It looks like `python-twitter` does not support python3 so you'll have to use Python 2.6.

The 2.6 error message is pretty clear:

```
"C:\Python26\twittersetup.py", line 13, in <module> long_description=open("./README", "r").read(), IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './README')
```

Basically you're attempting to run the script from another directory than the directory that contains the README file.

I'd start over and make sure you start by downloading and unpacking the complete source for `python-twitter`: http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-twitter/python-twitter-0.8.2.tar.gz

Next, uncompress and unpack the source ([7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) works nicely for this).

Then open up `cmd` and `cd` to that unpacked directory (which should include the README file and the setup.py file).  Then run something like:

```
C:\Python2.6\python2.6.exe setup.py
```

Comment: i dnt have any experience of cmd :( :(

Comment: Learning to use the CLI is very helpful for Python and there are quite a few resources out there to learn.  There are also guides for properly setting up Python on windows so that it works reasonably from the commandline.  (http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/cli-crash-coursech1.html, http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~rosario/classes/07F/202a/python/index.html, http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Python-packages-on-Windows-7/ ).

Comment: now i have some different error i do all the things !! oaah my GOd