# How to store name value pair in file

Tags: python, file, parsing, namevaluecollection

I have a large number of name value pair that I need to use in a program. What should be the best way to store the name value pair in a file so that I can easily parse them in my python program. For some reasons we are not using xml. Please suggest any good method to store them in a file and use them.

P.S -- The people writing the name value pairs in file need not be developers. They will be told to write certain values and they'll type. So i want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Probably, you can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module.

Comment: Regarding PS, yes I understand. Anyway we need to train them to write something right? Then it shouldn't be a difficult task. IMHO. :)

Answer (score 1):

**a.csv**
name1,value1
name2,value2

```
import csv
[i for i in csv.reader(open('a.csv').read().splitlines())]
```

[['name1', 'value1'], ['name2', 'value2']]

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON (recommended)
in python:

```
import json
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

or cvs

[enter http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: I had csv in mind. I planned like this   name1,value1,name2,value2,name3,value3, ......   If you feel you can add more structure to it, you are welcome. Json is a good option but again csv can be written via excel by any person.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as a python `dict` inside `.py` file itself and just import inside your script. If you'll come to know about the file name only at runtime use `__import__` to import the same. Ref [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__). By this way, you don't need to do any parse or conversion.

Comment: to elaborate on this, please consider also http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1027739/582906 but keeping in mind python3 compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357361/alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-2