# NameError: global name 'runfile' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I get the above error when I run this code:

```
from os import path, access, R_OK

ODBf = 'C:/Abaqus_JOBS/Reliability/Job-M1/Job-M1-3_run_rel2.odb'

if path.isfile(ODBf) or access(ODBf, R_OK):
    print 'file exists'
```

The file exists and the path to the file is correct. Where is the error? Thanks

Comment: It would help to include the full stack traceback.

Comment: @Aya: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: global name 'runfile' is not defined`

Comment: is "from os import path, access, R_OK" is the line no 1 in your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to run the code inside the Python interpreter by using a function called `runfile`, but there's no such function built-in to Python.

Assuming your script is in a file called `myscript.py`, it's most common to run a script from a command-line interpreter with...

```
$ python myscript.py
```

...although on Python 2.x, you can run it from inside the Python interpreter with...

```
>>> execfile('myscript.py')
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357361/alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-2) for the Python 3.x equivalent.

Comment: I'm using Spyder to run it. I'll try othe interpreter.