# Include/embed python file "as is"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import, python-import

For better code readability, let's suppose that I've got my code logically splitted in different python files, my main `main.py` file and an `included.py` file. I'd like to embed `included.py` inside of the main file.

I know it's possible to `import` it on `main.py` (e.g. `from included import *`), but, in some cases, objects/classes/variables on the `main.py` file may be imported on the `included.py` file too (e.g. `from main import *`).

What I'd like to do is to import the `included.py` file "as is" (like PHP does, with the `include` statement) on a specific position of my `main.py` file, by forcing the interpreter to read the content of the file and to place it on the specified position.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think its better to design in a way that you include only one file in another and not the cyclic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, try the execfile() command:

```
execfile('included.py')
```

In Python 3, try

```
exec(compile(open('included.py', "rb").read(), 'included.py', 'exec'))
```

I performed a simple test and this seems to work. Does it help in your case?

For more 'traditional' import ways:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749411/5172579

For the relation of Python2's execfile() and Python3's exec():
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357418/5172579

p.s. as noted in the comment: Cyclic imports should be avoided in general and can lead easily to infinite import recursions.