# Neovim throws an error when executing a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, neovim

I am getting an error message in neovim when executing a python3 file with `py3file %`.
It was working fine yesterday, I have made no changes in my configuration in the meantime.

The error I get is the following:

```
Error detected while processing function provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
Error invoking 'python_execute_file' on channel 4 (python3-script-host):
ch 4 was closed by the client
```

`:checkhealth provider` returns the following:

```
Python 3 provider (optional) ~
- Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/usr/bin/python3"
- Executable: /usr/bin/python3
- Python version: 3.11.5
- pynvim version: 0.4.3
- OK Latest pynvim is installed.

Python virtualenv ~
- OK no $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973559/nameerror-when-starting-neovim-while-python-virtual-environment-is-active) thread 'kind of' related to my problem, but it is related to virtual environment which I am not using in this case, and I do not understand the answer at all to be honest.

From other sources which I am not allowed to link here, I found that it is often related to settng `g:python3_host_prog` correctly. It was not set at all in my case, but, still `py3file %` was working fine yesterday. Anyway, it is now set to `/usr/bin/python3` and it has not changed anything.

I should add that the first time I run a python file after opening neovim, it gets executed before the error message is thrown, then, only the error gets thrown.

I tried updating everything, like `pynvim` with no effects.

Any idea on how to investigate this problem further would be greatly appreciated.