# install error or error running python file

Tags: python, python-idle

I am running a basic Python file on Windows XP from IDLE.

The file name is `assignment1.py`.
The file content is:

```
import sys
var = 5
```

but when I run it, it gives the error:

```
Command: python assignment1.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then I tried another thing which also gave an error:

```
Command: which python
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not sure if the installation is wrong or something.

I am able to run the print command successfully:

```
>>> print "I am working fine"
I am working fine
```

Not sure of the issue. Request help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are entering as the "command" is being interpreted as Python code. I mean, `python assignment1.py` is interpreted as Python code. The result is as expected:

```
$ python -c 'python assignment1.py'
  File "<string>", line 1
    python assignment1.py
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You need to run the file in the correct way, probably via the IDLE menu or by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. You can check these questions for details:

- [How do I run a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522564/how-do-i-run-a-python-program)
- [Running Python script from IDLE on Windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513967/running-python-script-from-idle-on-windows-7-64-bit)