# Creating and running a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, shell

sample.py is an existing python file.

Command to run that python file :

```
>>> python sample.py
```

Error message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to create and run a python file in a Python 2.7.14 shell.

Comment: I assume you are trying to run a python file from the terminal. If that is the case, you should type the command at the command line: `$ python sample.py`. I think the problem is that you first dropped to the Python REPL and tried to execute the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished using the `exec` function.  Assuming that `sample.py` has a single `print "hello world"` statement:

**Example**

```
>>> file = open('sample.py','r')
>>> exec(file.read())
hello world
```

You can read more about `exec()` and how to use it here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this with IDLE

Go to file or run and choose the py file.

Your issue is you are trying to run it in the repl.

Comment: Honestly for you man I recommend you download an IDE like pycharm

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513967/running-python-script-from-idle-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a Python file, you have to run it outside of the Python's REPL.

Open CMD or bash depending on your OS, `cd` to your python file's directory, then `python sample.py`.

Answer (score 1):

This must be happening because your are trying  `python sample.py` inside python shell, this would result in error because you are already inside python shell. Correct syntax in this case would be

```
exec(open("sample.py").read())
```

If you want to use `python sample.py` then this syntax will work in terminal of your OS.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using linux follow the below mentioned steps
[image: steps in Linux]
[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]
[image: step 3]

if you are using windows follow the below mentioned steps
[image: steps in windows]
[image: step 1]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**:  [From within your interactive shell]

If you want to execute a python *within your interactive shell* (as you are now, judging from your >>>) you can use the `%run` function. Assuming your file sample.py is in the same directore as where you are running the interactive shell.

Example:

```
>>> %run ./sample.py
```

(This assumes your script is located in the same directory where your interactive terminal is running. If not, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462540/9216538 on how to change the current directory).

**Solution 2**:  [From the command line in your normal terminal]

The standard option is to do this directly *from the normal command line in your terminal*. Open a regular terminal. Go to the directory where your python file is located with `cd path-to-file`.

Example:  [run this in your normal terminal]

```
python sample.py
```