# Activate a virtualenv with a Python script

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to activate a virtualenv instance from a Python script.

I know it's quite easy to do, but all the examples I've seen use it to run commands within the env and then close the subprocess.

I simply want to activate the virtualenv and return to the shell, the same way that bin/activate does.

Something like this:

```
$me: my-script.py -d env-name
$(env-name)me:
```

Is this possible?

Relevant:

*[virtualenv › Invoking an env from a script](http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/browse_thread/thread/15f8a9b0506abeae)*

Answer (score 120):

If you want to run a Python subprocess under the virtualenv, you can do that by running the script using the Python interpreter that lives inside virtualenv's `bin/` directory:

```
import subprocess

# Path to a Python interpreter that runs any Python script
# under the virtualenv /path/to/virtualenv/
python_bin = "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python"

# Path to the script that must run under the virtualenv
script_file = "must/run/under/virtualenv/script.py"

subprocess.Popen([python_bin, script_file])
```

However, if you want to activate the virtualenv under the current Python interpreter instead of a subprocess, you can call [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#execfile) passing the `activate_this.py` script, like this:

```
# Doing exec() on this file will alter the current interpreter's
# environment so you can import libraries in the virtualenv
activate_this_file = "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py"

exec(open(activate_this_file).read(), {'__file__': activate_this_file})
```

Note that you need to use the [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) library, not [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), for the above.

If you use venv, you can copy the implementation of virtualenv's activate_this.py, it should still more or less work with venv with just a few minor changes.

Comment: // , Shouldn't that last line in the first code block on this answer read as follows: `subprocess.Popen([venv_python_file, script_file])` ?

Comment: // , Also, is there a way to run the `script_file` from an arbitrary location, or does it have to be in the `virtualenv` directory?

Comment: Fixed, thanks for noticing the error. As to for your second question, no `script_file` doesn't have to be in virtualenv directory, it can be anywhere.

Comment: How can I deactivate the virtual env, if I'm using the second option?

Comment: @falsePockets: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/148108), why do you ever want to do that?

Comment: To solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462260/runnning-python-nose-tests-in-virtual-env).

I have a bunch of 'modules' which will each be uploaded to AWS as a AWS 'lambda function' (where lambda in an AWS context has a slightly different meaning to a python context).
They each use different libraries, so they each need different virtual envs.

I have a python script that runs unit tests and uploads each module to AWS. Each test needs to be done in it's respective virtual env.

Comment: How do you do this using the second option and python3? Looks like exec has replaced execfile in python3, but I'm not able to get it to work.

Comment: @djsosofresh I was also investigating this and in the comments of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33637414/8691571 I got the info from 
ShadowRanger that it is not possible. I guess we have not understood Lie Ryan's answer well enough.

Comment: The third party module `virtualenv` still works for Python 3, if you just want things to work, use that instead of the built-in `venv` or `pyvenv` to create your virtual environment. The ShadowRanger answer that you linked also pointed out a workaround if you insist on using the built-in version of the module, you can just copy the `activate_this.py` from the third party `virtualenv` module into your project. It's not impossible to make it work in `venv`, though it may be a bit involved.

Comment: @djsosofresh This worked for me in Python 3.6 apparently: `exec(compile(open(activate_this_file, "rb").read(), activate_this_file, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this_file))`

Comment: O. My. Gosh. Never had I noticed `activate_this.py` inside of virtual env directory. Thank you so much for the hint. :))

Answer (score 80):

The simplest solution to run your script under virtualenv's interpreter is to replace the default shebang line with path to your virtualenv's interpreter like so at the beginning of the script:

```
#!/path/to/project/venv/bin/python
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x script.py
```

Run the script:

```
./script.py
```

Voila!

Comment: +1 for elegance.  Note on windows this requires a posix compliant environment that understands shebang lines like cygwin or msys

Comment: Works for python 3.6.3 and windows 10!

Comment: Think I might have misunderstood the original question.  He wants to activate the virtual environment with a script and return to shell with the activated environment.  My answer runs script in the virtual environment but the returned shell does not retain the environment.   The modern day solution is virtualenvwrapper: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#.  It allows one to activate and switch between different virtualenvs.

Comment: This works like magic!

Comment: Could anyone please post an working example for this? Its quite confusing since you are using the commands like those in a command prompt and not a python script.

Answer (score 27):

To run another Python environment according to the official [Virtualenv documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/16.7.9/userguide.html#activate-script), in the command line you can specify the full path to the executable Python binary, just that (no need to active the virtualenv before):

```
/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python
```

The same applies if you want to invoke a script from the command line with your virtualenv. You don't need to activate it before:

```
me$ /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python myscript.py
```

The same for a Windows environment (whether it is from the command line or from a script):

```
> \path\to\env\Scripts\python.exe myscript.py
```

Comment: Question is: Activate a virtualenv with a python script (NOT from Shell)

Comment: Yes, my point is that you can just call the python runtime from a virtual environment without the need to activate it before, from the console or from a script. I will clarify the answer, thanks!

Comment: Oh my goodness! I didn't think about it. this is the only solution that worked for me :). Now, When I am executing python script from php, I am using: "path/to/virtualenv/bin/python mypythonscript.py"

Answer (score 25):

It turns out that, yes, the problem is not simple, but the solution is.

First I had to create a shell script to wrap the "source" command. That said I used the "." instead, because I've read that it's better to use it than source for Bash scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/to/env/bin/activate
```

Then from my Python script I can simply do this:

```
import os
os.system('/bin/bash --rcfile /path/to/myscript.sh')
```

The whole trick lies within the `--rcfile` argument.

When the Python interpreter exits it leaves the current shell in the activated environment.

Win!

Comment: I really don't get it.
Why don't you just do that :
`os.system('/bin/bash  --rcfile path/to/env/activate')`    
You know, when an instance of bash is started, it takes .bashrc as an argument for the --rcfile. So just specify that the rcfile is your activate file... No ?

Comment: @Depado I just tried your solution and this will activate the shell within python.  at least when I try it in the shell.

>>> os.system('/bin/bash --rcfile /var/envs/test/bin/activate')
(test)tcraig@tallis-desktop:~$ 
(test)tcraig@tallis-desktop:~$ ls -l
total 706288

Comment: Maybe but this works in a script. The only inconvenient with this technique is that you don't get all your aliases and everything you had in your ~/.bashrc. But I'm fine with it. For example the "ls" command has no color. But everything works for me.  When I want to leave, I just Ctrl+D

Comment: "When the python interpreter exits it leave the current shell in the activated environment" What? It spawns a totally new shell as a subprocess and waits until it finishes.

Comment: In order to avoid creating more new files on my repository and to also replicate the current bash config, I did this: `cat ~/.bashrc env/bin/activate > env/bin/activate2 && /bin/bash --rcfile env/bin/activate2`

Answer (score 8):

Just a simple solution that works for me. I don't know why you need the Bash script which basically does a useless step (am I wrong ?)

```
import os
os.system('/bin/bash  --rcfile flask/bin/activate')
```

Which basically does what you need:

```
[hellsing@silence Foundation]$ python2.7 pythonvenv.py
(flask)[hellsing@silence Foundation]$
```

Then instead of deactivating the virtual environment, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or exit. Is that a possible solution or isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 8):

The top answer only works for Python 2.x

For Python 3.x, use this:

```
activate_this_file = "/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py"

exec(compile(open(activate_this_file, "rb").read(), activate_this_file, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this_file))
```

Reference: *[What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3)*

Comment: what is activate_this.py

Comment: @randyPen, the activate_this.py file is automatically added when you build the virtualenv in your project directory. (i.e. /project/directory/venv/bin/activate_this.py)

Comment: note that Python does not use the same dir structure on all operating systems, so this is not a universal solution (neither are any of the other questions, but it'd be nice if it were updated to "just work(tm)" instead of not working on any windows machine)

Answer (score 2):

The child process environment is lost in the moment it ceases to exist, and moving the environment content from there to the parent is somewhat tricky.

You probably need to spawn a shell script (you can generate one dynamically to /tmp) which will output the virtualenv environment variables to a file, which you then read in the parent Python process and put in os.environ.

Or you simply parse the activate script in using for the line in open("bin/activate"), manually extract stuff, and put in os.environ. It is tricky, but not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

For python2/3, Using below code snippet we can activate virtual env.

```
activate_this = "/home/<--path-->/<--virtual env name -->/bin/activate_this.py" #for ubuntu
activate_this = "D:\<-- path -->\<--virtual env name -->\Scripts\\activate_this.py" #for windows
with open(activate_this) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), activate_this, 'exec')
    exec(code, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: surely it would make more sense to not have to guess, and just ask `platform.system()` which OS we're in, then set `activate_this` to what it needs to be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and there was no `activate_this.py` in the `Scripts` directory of my environment.

activate_this.py

```py
"""By using execfile(this_file, dict(__file__=this_file)) you will
activate this virtualenv environment.
This can be used when you must use an existing Python interpreter, not
the virtualenv bin/python
"""

try:
    __file__
except NameError:
    raise AssertionError(
        "You must run this like execfile('path/to/active_this.py', dict(__file__='path/to/activate_this.py'))")
import sys
import os

base = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if(sys.platform=='win32'):
     site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'Lib', 'site-packages')
else:
     site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
import site
site.addsitedir(site_packages)
sys.real_prefix = sys.prefix
sys.prefix = base
# Move the added items to the front of the path:
new_sys_path = []
for item in list(sys.path):
    if item not in prev_sys_path:
        new_sys_path.append(item)
        sys.path.remove(item)
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
```

Copy the file to the `Scripts` directory of your environment and use it like this:

```py
def activate_virtual_environment(environment_root):
    """Configures the virtual environment starting at ``environment_root``."""
    activate_script = os.path.join(
        environment_root, 'Scripts', 'activate_this.py')
    execfile(activate_script, {'__file__': activate_script})

activate_virtual_environment('path/to/your/venv')
```

Refrence: https://github.com/dcreager/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv_support/activate_this.py

Answer (score 0):

Related to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14792407/22851801) about `activate_this.py`

If that's your use case (activate the virtualenv on the same process), you may be interested in using [activate-virtualenv](https://github.com/usernein/activate-virtualenv), a context manager that does the activation and deactivation of virtualenvs automatically, based on the `activate_this.py` script.

Example of usage:

```
from activate_virtualenv import activate_virtualenv

venv_path = "/path/to/virtualenv"
with activate_virtualenv(venv_path):
    import subscript1
```

Then "`subscript1.py`" will be imported with the virtualenv activated. It will be able to load any modules installed on the activated virtualenv. AFter the `with` block ends, the virtualenv will be automatically deactivated and the changes made by `activate_this.py` will be undone, so it will not affect the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say how I'm interpreting this question:

> Is there a way that I can run a command which will cause a certain virtualenv (among several) to become active in my interactive shell?

And the short answer is:

Not without help from the shell -- because any command that you write in a normal way will be a sub-process, and will not be able to modify settings in the shell directly.

That said, there are ways to get help from the shell, so, for example, suppose one has a script that's something like the following (pseudo-code):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

# writing this function is an exercise for the reader...
# I don't know what you're wanting to do here, but I'll
# assume you have some way to choose a venv directory
# based on command-line arguments:
env_dir = choose_env_dir_based_on(sys.ARGV)
print(f". #{env_dir}/bin/activate")
```

Now, supposing (based on the question text) you want to be able to run this as `my-script.py -d env-name` (I'd probably drop the `.py` from that, but I'll run with it, since that's how the question was phrased), let's save that in a file called, say, `~/bin/_my-script.py`.  From there, you need to teach your shell how to run that command in a way that can modify its own environment.  You can do this in a couple of different ways.  The easiestway is probably with an alias:

```bash
alias my-script.py='eval `~/bin/_myscript.py`'
```

However, this has the drawback that it doesn't have a good way to get arguments to it, so running `my-script.py -d env-name` won't really work (though if you just need to run `my-script.py`, then it would).  Instead, one could do it with a shell function:

```bash
my-script.py () { eval `~/bin/_my-script.py "$@"` }
```

Whichever you go with, you'd presumably save that in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, or whatever equivalent for the shell you happen to be using.

With the function form, this then allows one to *type* `my-script.py -d env-name`, while having it actually do the following:

1. Run `~/bin/_my-script.py` (with `-d env-name` supplied as arguments).
2. Take the output of that script, and `eval` it (see, e.g., [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23117/2977) for more information), so that it runs *within the context of your shell*.
3. And since what `_my-script.py` actually does is to print out a shell command to source the activate script for the relevant directory, that will then happen.

---

## Bonus: self-activating scripts:

So, the above is all answering the question that was asked.  I came to this answer trying to find a solution for a different question, though.  My question could be summarized as:

> Can I have a python script run *as though* it had been run with a particular venv already set?

For this, something like the following could be run (I found my own solution).  For the sake of this example, I'll assume that the venv is in a directory called `.env` that exists alongside the script that's being run.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# the above "shebang" line references whatever python3
# we happen to have, whether or not an environment is set.

# But we want to run with the environment in .env relative
# to the current script, unless an env is activated (in
# which case, we'd use that, and do nothing special here):

import os, sys

if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' not in os.environ:
  # assuming .env is next to this script:
  venv = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
  # finding the python from that env:
  newpython = os.path.join(venv, 'bin', 'python')
  # setting up a new ARGV, to start with the new python:
  args = [newpython] + sys.argv
  # Note: setting VIRTUAL_ENV isn't what causes the
  # virtualenv to be utilized.  Python has some other means
  # of doing that.  But it does signal to the if condition
  # above to not run this code more than once (lest we
  # go into an infinite execv loop).
  os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'] = venv
  # With that all set up, we re-run under the new python:
  os.execv(newpython, args)

import somemodule # something pip installed inside the venv.

# rest of code here
```

Or, for a terse version of just what we need to force the venv:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' not in os.environ:
  venv = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
  newpython = os.path.join(venv, 'bin', 'python')
  args = [newpython] + sys.argv
  os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'] = venv
  os.execv(newpython, args)
```

("Reasonable" error messaging upon the lack of existence of the `.env` directory is left as an exercise for the reader.
As-is, a `FileNotFoundError` error will be raised when attempting to run `os.execv`.  What's "reasonable" is presumably dependent upon what one wants -- to automatically create the venv?  To just report an error?  Other?  Hence leaving it as an exercise.)

Answer (score -1):

You should create all your `virtualenv`s in one folder, such as `virt`.

Assuming your virtualenv folder name is virt, if not change it

```
cd
mkdir custom
```

Copy the below lines...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ENV_PATH="$HOME/virt/$1/bin/activate"
bash --rcfile $ENV_PATH -i
```

Create a shell script file and paste the above lines...

```
touch custom/vhelper
nano custom/vhelper
```

Grant executable permission to your file:

```
sudo chmod +x custom/vhelper
```

Now export that custom folder path so that you can find it on the command-line by clicking tab...

export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/custom"

Now you can use it from anywhere by just typing the below command...

```
vhelper YOUR_VIRTUAL_ENV_FOLDER_NAME
```

Suppose it is abc then...

```
vhelper abc
```