# Running subprocess within different virtualenv with python

Tags: python, virtualenv

Let's say I have 2 different versions of my app installed in 2 different virtualenvironments. myapp v1.0 and myapp v2.0.

Now I would like to compare those. The comparison is written in python itself. What would be the best way to do that? Let's assume I can run them separately and both write an output file, which I can compare later.

One way to do that would be to write a bash script (that's what I have currently). I activate one virtualenv, run myapp v1.0, activate another virtualenv, run myapp v2.0. Later run a comparison module on those files. But I would like to add some more dynamics there (take some optional arguments etc) which would be easier with python.

Currently I have something like that (a bash script):

```
source virtualenv1/bin/activate
python my_script.py
deactivate

source virtualenv2/bin/activate
python my_other_script.py
deactivate

python my_comparison_script.py
```

instead, I'd like to do only:

```
python my_comparison_script.py
```

and my scripts would be run inside this.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you start your application with a call to the python executable, like in your example it is actually very simple: you only have to explicitly point to the executable in the virtualenv.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["virtualenv1/bin/python", "my_script.py"])
subprocess.Popen(["virtualenv2/bin/python", "my_other_script.py"])
```

will start the processes in the respective virtualenvs.

**Important**

To address the concerns voiced in the comments:

If you want to run a subprocess and be sure to use **the same interpreter** that the current process is running in you have to use [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.executable). Also available: [sys.exec_prefix](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.exec_prefix) to access the site-specific directory prefix where the platform-dependent Python files are installed.

If you want a much more in depth discussion of this topic, have a look at this [pull request](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/1080).

Comment: Actually, this is not enough. Activating a virtualenv also changes some environment variables, calling specific virutalenv's python doesn't do that. As a result, wrong libraries will be loaded.

Comment: @qarma: I disagree - this approach works and I am using it in my own production code. I am [not the only one recommending it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14792407/2626627), either. I would be helpful if you concretize the environment variables you are referring to and provide a test case that shows under wich circumstances wrong libraries would be loaded.

Comment: Yes I've seen that recommendation on virtualenv's site too. There are at least two cases where running with virtualenv linked python interpreter directly is different from using activate: when `PYTHONHOME` is set and when target program uses `command` or `Popen` to run another Python program. The latter if arguably murky.

Comment: I just tried the second scenario and that's true: calling subprocess from inside my_script.py would be exectuted with the system Python again. Awkward.

Comment: On windows. I need to "set PYTHONPATH= & workon virtualenv1" before calling python or the script.  Otherwise, the python interpreter  PYTHONPATH still points back to the system libraries.

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this but how does tox handle this?

Answer (score 15):

I think **virtualenv** documentation explains it nicely.

**TL;DR**

Runnig python venv binary directly is **NOT** the same as activating venv.
You also have to change *PATH* and *VIRTUAL_ENV* variables accordingly (look at [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ))

[Source](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/16.7.9/userguide.html)

> $ source /path/to/ENV/bin/activate
>
> This will change your $PATH so its first entry is the virtualenv’s
> bin/ directory. (You have to use source because it changes your shell
> environment in-place.) This is all it does; it’s purely a convenience.
>
> If you directly run a script or the python interpreter from the
> virtualenv’s bin/ directory (e.g. path/to/ENV/bin/pip or
> /path/to/ENV/bin/python-script.py) then sys.path will automatically be
> set to use the Python libraries associated with the virtualenv. But,
> unlike the activation scripts, the environment variables PATH and
> VIRTUAL_ENV will not be modified. This means that if your Python
> script uses e.g. subprocess to run another Python script (e.g. via a
> !/usr/bin/env python shebang line) the second script may not be executed with the same Python binary as the first nor have the same
> libraries available to it. To avoid this happening your first script
> will need to modify the environment variables in the same manner as
> the activation scripts, before the second script is executed.

Answer (score 12):

A simple option would be to run a series of commands with subprocess as follows (note that `shell=True` is risky and should only be used if you can control the input).

```
import subprocess
    
cmd = 'source activate my_virtualenv; python my_script.py'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

And repeat as needed.

Comment: `Source` won't be available inside subprocess because subprocess uses /bin/sh. This will give the error: "/bin/sh: 1: source: not found"

Comment: Use `.` instead of `source`, which is the portable equivalent

Comment: Perhaps highight that the effects of `source` will disappear when `subprocess.call` finishes. The main meat here is running your main Python script in the same subprocess as the `source` command, which is often unattractive for other reasons. (Maybe instead then run a shell script which does the `source` and _then_ runs your entire Python script.)