# Python calling subprocess that requires no virtual environment

Tags: python, subprocess, virtual, environment

I have a Python 3.6 script that calls out to a third-party tool using subprocess.

`main_script.py:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['third-party-tool', '-arg1'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem is, `main_script.py` must be run from within a virtual environment, and `third-party-tool` must be run from no virtual environment whatsoever.

I don't know much about `third-party-tool`, except that it is on my path. Calling it while I have a virtual environment active causes it to jam up and throw an exception later on. I do not know if it uses the default python binary or it it spins up its own virtual env and does stuff in there. It is not a Python script, but apparently calls one somehow.

*How do I tell subprocess to drop out of my virtual environment and run the command in the default shell environment?*

I've examined a couple of similar questions:

- [Running subprocess within different virtualenv with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052926/running-subprocess-within-different-virtualenv-with-python) -- In the first case, they are specifying the environment by calling their script with a specific version of Python. `third-party-tool` is not a Python script (I believe it's bash).
- [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment) -- In the second case, they're tweaking existing environment variables, which looks promising, but I want to reset to the default environment, and I'm not sure if I necessarily know which variables I need to clear or reset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of subprocess:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

The accepted args are

```
subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
    capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False,
    encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None)
```

In particular,

> If env is not None, it must be a mapping that defines the environment variables for the new process; these are used instead of the default behavior of inheriting the current process’ environment. It is passed directly to Popen.

Thus, passing an empty dictionary `env={}` (start with empty environment) and using `bash --login` (run as login shell, which reads env defaults) should do the trick.

```
subprocess.run(['bash', '--login', '-c', '/full/path/to/third-party-tool', '-arg1'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env={})
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help, nullUser; your solution is a concise and correct answer to my question.

However, when I tried it out, my third-party-tool now fails for some other (unknown) reason. There was probably some other environment variable I don't know about that's getting lost with the new shell. Fortunately, I found an alternate solution which I'll share for anyone else struggling.

### My Solution

*As far as I can tell, the only difference that entering the virtual environment does to my environment is add a new path to my PATH variable, and add the variable VIRTUAL_ENV.*

I can replicate the outside-virtual-environment behavior by creating a copy of my environment where I:

- delete that VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable and
- remove the python prefix from PATH.

### Example

#### my_script.py

`my_script.py` Implements my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, os, sys

env = os.environ.copy()
if hasattr(sys,'real_prefix'):
    # If in virtual environment, gotta forge a copy of the environment, where we:
    # Delete the VIRTUAL_ENV variable.
    del(env['VIRTUAL_ENV'])

    # Delete the "/home/me/.python_venv/main/bin:" from the front of my PATH variable.
    orig_path = env['PATH']
    virtual_env_prefix = sys.prefix + '/bin:'
    env['PATH'] = orig_path.replace(virtual_env_prefix, '')

# Pass the environment into the third party tool, modified if and when required.
subprocess.run(['./third-party-tool'], shell=False, env=env)
```

#### third-party-tool

`third-party-tool` is mocked out as a script that tells you if it's in a virtual environment and prints out environment variables. In this example, `third-party-tool` is a Python script but in general it might not be.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# third-party-tool
import sys, os
in_venv = hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix')
print('This is third-party Tool and you {} in a virtual environment.'.format("ARE" if in_venv else "ARE NOT"))
os.system('env')
```

#### Testing

Now I try calling third-party-tool from outside virtual environment, inside virtual environment, and from the python script in the virtual environment, capturing the output.

```
[me@host ~]$ ./third-party-tool > without_venv.txt
# Now I activate virtual environment
(main) [me@host ~]$ ./third-party-tool > within_venv.txt
(main) [me@host ~]$ ./my_script.py > within_venv_from_python.txt
```

Note: the outputs looks like this:
    This is third-party Tool and you ARE NOT in a virtual environment.
    (Proceeds to pring out a list of KEY=VALUE environment variables)

I use my favorite diff tool and compare the outputs. `within_venv_from_python.txt` is identical to `without_venv.txt`, which is a good sign (in both cases, `third-party-tool` runs with same environment variables, and indicates it is not living in the matrix). After implementing this solution, my actual third-party-tool appears to be working.