# .venv through a Python Script

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to open a python script through another python script in a separate command window.
The code I am using is something like:

PythonScript1.py:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["path\to\another\python script.py"], shell=True)
```

Now this is opening the second script in a new window but with a major issue.
It's not running on the venv which has all the packages installed. Instead it's running on the default interpreter. This is causing lots of errors as it is not able to locate the packages.

Is there a way so that I can open the second script via the first one while making sure both the script run on the venv?

I scoured the internet but every time I came across either of the two issues: Either it ran in the same terminal as the first program or in cases where it didn't it throwed an error of not being able to find a package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running subprocess within different virtualenv with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052926/running-subprocess-within-different-virtualenv-with-python)

Comment: Do you mean that you execute PythonScript1.py already in the venv and want to start the subprocess in the same venv?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the interpreter provided by the venv. It's usually located at `<name of your venv>/Scripts/python` or `<name of your venv>/bin/python`.

Example code if your venv folder is named `my-venv`:

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(["my-venv/Scripts/python", "script.py"])
```

^ note that it's recommended to not use `shell=True` and instead you should pass the args as separate strings in the argument list.

Since the parent process script is also running on the venv, a safer and better route is to use `sys.executable`, which will give you the absolute path to the Python interpreter that the current script is running on, ensuring that both will run on the same interpreter (the venv interpreter). Using this method, you can write

```py
import sys

/* the rest of your code */

process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "path/to/script.py"])
```

Additionally, if you want to force the process to open in a new console window, you can use the flag `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` like so:

```py
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "path/to/script.py"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use `&&` to combine multiple commands in one. For example:

`cd path/to/folder && ./venv/bin/activate && python script.py` on Linux

or `cd /d path\\to\\folder && venv/scripts/acticate && python script.py` on Windows