# Deployment of flask application on windows

Tags: python, windows, flask, deployment

Here I need to deploy flask application on windows but I am not getting clarity of steps .Can anyone suggest me some steps of deploying flask application on windows

Comment: maybe this helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62512179/12368419

Comment: for `apache` if have `xampp` or `wampserver` .. that's fine. What kind of error you get with `mod_wsgi` ?

Comment: I have installed apache only should i install xampp or wampserver and it's location is C:/Apache24

Comment: i suggest you installing `wampserver` because the given link (my answer) assumes `wampserver` installed and then you can adapt the logic even on linux server and nginx

Comment: And what about installed apache should i delete it

Comment: you can ignore it, for moment, if you set the right path in `%APACHE_HOME%` environment variable

Comment: Now its solved it's added some apache_home path and mod_wsgi_root_dir  path to system variable under environment variable