# How to set FLASK_APP with custom project structure

Tags: python, flask

Despite trial and error I cannot get the command 'flask shell' to run.

This is what happens when i run `flask shell` from the project dir:

`$ set FLASK_APP=`

> Error: While importing "project_dir.wsgi", an ImportError was raised:
> [...] from flask_app.app import construct_app ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'flask_app'

`$ set FLASK_APP=wsgi`

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'

`$ set FLASK_APP=flask_app\__init__.py:construct_app`

> Error: module 'backoffice_nova.flask_app' has no attribute 'construct_app'

`$ set FLASK_APP=flask_app:contruct_app("development")`

> Error: module 'backoffice_nova.flask_app' has no attribute 'contruct_app'

My project structure looks like this

```
    /project_dir
    .
    +-- flask_app
    ¦   +-- __init__.py
    ¦   +-- app
    ¦       +-- main
    ¦       ¦   +-- __init__.py
    ¦       +-- static
    ¦       +-- templates
    ¦       +--models.py
    ¦       +-- __init__.py
    +-- src
    ¦   +-- __init__.py
    ¦   +-- ...
    +-- tests
    ¦   +-- __init__.py
    ¦   +-- ...
    +-- environment.yml
    +-- wsgi.py
    +-- config.py
```

To start the app I normally run wsgi.py

```py
#wsgi.py
from flask_app.app import construct_app
app = construct_app("development")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask will automatically find the application instance if you put the app in `wsgi.py` or `app.py` and name the instance as `app` or `application`, so you don't need to set the `FLASK_APP`.

Besides, you can explicitly set it as:

```
$ set FLASK_APP=wsgi
```

or:

```
$ set FLASK_APP=flask_app:contruct_app("development")
```

See more about [application discovery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#application-discovery) in the docs.

Comment: I've also tried setting FLASK_APP to wsgi. Then I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'`. I've updated the top post.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you this good read on [How to Run a Flask Application](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application) from Miguel GRINBERG.

instead of manually setting `FLASK_APP` on `windows cmd` or `Power Shell` just create `.flaskenv` file under the root of your project and add the `Flask` related environment variables (don't forget to install `python-dotenv` package)

i usually import my `Flask` app as a `package` not `module` and as a good practice `__init__.py` is kept for `imports` and some `metadata` like (`__author__` and `__version__`)

and with a good project structure, you can make your app maintainable, easy to debug, extensible and easy to deploy

i usually set the structure of my `flask` project to some thing similar to below.

have a look at `.flaskenv`, `__init__.py`, `flaskdemo.py` and `wsgi.py` files

## project structure

```
flaskdemo / the root folder project

.. 

.. congfigs
     __init__.py
     base.py
     development.py
     production.py
     testing.py

.. flaskdemo

   .. 

   .. errors (blueprint)
        templates
        __init__.py
        views.py

   .. main (blueprint)
      .. static
      .. templates
      .. __init__.py
      .. forms.py
      .. models.py
      .. views.py
      .. utils.py

   .. static
   .. templates
   .. __init__.py
   .. extensions.py
   .. flaskdemo.py

.. tests
.. venv
.. .flaskenv
.. wsgi.py
.. environment.yml

..
```

## /.flaskenv

```
FLASK_APP=flaskdemo:create_app('development')
# FLASK_APP=flaskdemo:create_app('testing')
# FLASK_APP=flaskdemo:create_app('production')

FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=0
```

## /flaskdemo/__init __.py

```
from .flaskdemo import create_app
```

## /flaskdemo/flaskdemo.py

```
from flask import Flask
[..]

def create_app(config_object):
    """Create a Flask application using the app factory pattern."""

    app = Flask(__name__)

    load_config(app, config_object)

    init_app_extensions(app)  
    register_blueprints(app)

    [..]

    return app
```

## /flaskdemo/wsgi.py

below how i do to serve `flask` app on windows using `apache` and `mod_wsgi`

```
import os
import sys

# activate virtualenv
PROJECT = "flaskdemo"

# py -m venv
# @see: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html
# @see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020451/no-activate-this-py-file-in-venv-pyvenv

activate_this = os.path.join(os.environ['PYTHON_HOME'], 'myapps/flask', PROJECT, 'venv/Scripts/activate_this.py')
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
if BASE_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)

from helloflask import create_app
application = create_app('development')
# application = create_app('testing')
# application = create_app('production')
```