# How to import global and virtual environment packages in Rodeo?

Tags: python-2.7, rodeo

I have recently installed Tensorflow in a virtual environment and its working fine. I previously installed numpy,pandas,matplotlib and other packages as global packages(python 2.7). I want to  use Tensorflow with other global packages using rodeo IDE.

I have successfully imported all packages this way using terminal

```
virtualenv env --system-site-packages 
source /media/usr/dir/tensor/bin/activate
python -c "import tensorflow;print(tensorflow.__version__)"
0.10.0
python -c "import numpy;print(numpy.__version__)"
1.11.1
```

In rodeo I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944649/996366) `ten.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
virtualenv env --system-site-packages 
source /media/usr/dir/tensor/bin/activate
```

Inside rodeo IDE

```
#rodeo
import os
os.system('/bin/bash --rcfile /media/usr/dir/tensor/ten.sh')

0
```

but when tried to  import tensorflow its giving me error

> ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import tensorflow

I also tried to change the path of the python (default to /media/usr/dir/tensor/bin/python) from IDE itself but after changing when I import any pacakges it return

```
>>> import tensorflow
This socket has been ended by the other party
```