# Python script to activate and keep open a Virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I need a python script that will activate a virtualenv, run another python program inside the virtualenv, and then close the virutalenv after the second python program closes. Here is my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

activate_dir = "C:/Users/JohnDoe/theprogram/Scripts/"
os.chdir(activate_dir)
subprocess.Popen(["activate.bat"])

cal_dir = "C:/Users/JohnDoe/theprogram/"
os.chdir(cal_dir)
os.system('python program_file.py')
```

However, when this code run, I get an import error from the `program_file` which means the virtualenv is not activated. How can I fix this?

Thanks

**Edit:**
This is on a Windows environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script

Comment: From my understanding, the question linked is about using a python script to exclusively activate a virtualenv. My questions adds to that by changing a directory and running another python file while the virtualenv is activated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating a new process with subprocess.Popen(["activate.bat"]) that is using that virtual environment, you're not changing your environment. What you need to do is to either call the python script in the same process you span:

```
os.system("source activate;python -V")
```

Or you could write a shell script that starts the virtual environment and calls any python script you send to it. In bash (on linux) this would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start a virtual environment and call a python module
# usage: ./runVirenvPythonModule module.py
source activate
python $1 # this is the first cmd line argument passed in
```

Comment: Ah, nice answer! If I use the `os.system` command, how would I go from the `Scripts` dir where I call `activate` to the `program` dir where I call the python script?

Comment: Please note the M$ Windows-style path in OP's code. And the fact that the activation is done via a batch file. Using bash syntax in windows will be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a method to detect, activate, and create (if needed) a virtual environment inside a Python script and run inside that virtual environment while remaining inside that script and without the use of shell commands issued from that script (except to display installed packages via *pip list*). Without the use of shell commands, the script becomes OS agnostic.

Here is some example code. You simply run it from whatever OS shell you are using (Windows, Linux, MacOS):

```
import os
import sys
import venv

def isvirtualenv():
    return sys.prefix != sys.base_prefix

def findfile(startdir, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startdir):
        for name in files:
            if name.find(pattern) >= 0:
                return root + os.sep + name

    return None

venv_path = 'venv'            # This is an example path

if isvirtualenv():
    print('Already in virtual environment.')
else:
    if findfile(os.getcwd(), 'activate') is None:
        print('No virtual environment found. Creating one.')
        env = venv.EnvBuilder(with_pip = True)
        env.create(venv_path)
    else:
        print('Not in virtual environment. Virtual environment directory found.')

    # This is the heart of this script that puts you inside the virtual environment. 
    # There is no need to undo this. When this script ends, your original path will 
    # be restored.
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.dirname(findfile(os.getcwd(), 'activate')) + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
    sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(findfile(venv_path, 'easy_install.py')))

# Run your script inside the virtual environment from here
print(os.environ['PATH'])
os.system('pip list')
```

Comment: At least on my system (Windows 10) and in my virtual environments, the last line will point not to `site-packages` within the virtual environment (I think that's the intention) but to `site-packages/setuptools/command`. Maybe a better alternative would be `findfile` for `setuptools` directory, directly?