# Activate a Python virtualenv from a Node script

Tags: python, node.js, virtualenv

I'm writing a Node script where I install Python modules using pip. I'd like to activate a virtualenv and then install pip modules in that virtualenv. I could do something like the following:

```
proc.execFile("virtualenv", { args: "venv" }, function() {
    proc.execFile("source", { args: "venv/bin/activate" }, function() {
        proc.execFile("pip", { args: ["install", "myPipModule"]}, function() {
                                // do stuff
        });
    });
});
```

The issue with this is that it would lose the context of my virtualenv and so wouldn't install the modules where I want them. How can I keep the context of my virtualenv in my Node script so `pip install` puts modules in the right place?

---

**Note**: Similar to [this question for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script) but I'm using Node.

Comment: not too familiar with node, but it looks like you're basically running command line.  Can you run something like `proc.execFile("workon", {args:"<VENV_NAME>"})`.  I guess this assumes you have virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: The answer is the same as in the question you've pointed to — you don't need to activate virtual env to run `pip` in it — you just use `python` from the virtual env with full path.

Comment:  Of course! Go ahead and make this into a full answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to activate a virtual env to run `pip` in it, you just use the path of the `pip` binary in the virtualenv and it will install it within that `virtualenv`.

```
proc.execFile("myapp/venv/bin/pip", { args: ["install", "myPipModule"]}, function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: How would you actiavte a virtual environment in generel?

Comment: @J.Doe typically you'd run something like `source virtualenv/bin` assuming your virtualenvironment is called `virtualenv`

Comment: I do run this command, but without success. I'm asking because I have exact this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875421/activating-an-virtual-environment-from-python-in-nodejs