# Activating an virtual environment from python in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, virtual-environment

I have following project on a raspberry pi 4:
I created a face recognition script in python which needs an virtual enviroment to run.
The script prints out the person which has been detected.

In NodeJS I want to receive the answer by running the script in node (minified version):

```
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
py    = spawn('python', ['faceReg.py'],)
py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log('Data:' + data);

});
py.stdout.on('end', function(){
  console.log('Python ended');


 });

});
```

When executing the code I get immdeaitly an "python ended".

On my pi I can run the script when I run following command before execution:

```
source ~/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/activate
```

The python script is basicly:

```
stop = False
while(stop==False):
   print("Peter")
```

**Update**

When running

```
py    = spawn('~/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python', ['faceReg.py'])
```

I get following error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn ~/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

This is my file system:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Activating the virtual environment must be done in the script itself. Outside of that will not take effect.

Similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934840/activate-a-python-virtualenv-from-a-node-script/54480966?noredirect=1#comment102253718_54480966), you'll just want to execute the Python runtime that's listed in your virtual environment. That question references `pip` but you can essentially just replace it with the version of Python you want (that exists in your virtual environment). In other words, you would replace this line:

```
py    = spawn('python', ['faceReg.py'],)
```

With this line:

```
py    = spawn('/home/youruser/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python', ['faceReg.py'],)
```

**Note:** If this fails, you may need to change `/home/youruser/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python` to be whatever version of Python you're looking for e.g. `/home/youruser/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python3` or `/home/youruser/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python3.7`.

Comment: I updated my question. I get the error that the directory cant be found

Comment: @J.Doe try using the absolute path. When you're in the directory in the terminal, type in `pwd`, which will return something like `'/home/user/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python'`. Use that output in your script instead of using `~/.virtualenvs/cv2_env/bin/python`

Comment: I get no error now. It seems to start. But I get a "Python ended" after some time. But I think I should start a new question for this. Thanks for the help!