# Module not found in virtualenv

Tags: python, module, virtualenv

I use a virtualenv to pip install packages. To run my script, I need the command:

```
command = "env/bin/python main.py"
```

If I type the command in the terminal directly, it is working. However, if I run it in

```
os.system(command)
```

The script is stopped and feedback "xxx is not found". I checked that in the latter case, the used python is not the one in the virtualenv, but the one in the system.

BTW: The suggested answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate a virtualenv with a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+subprocess