# How can I use a python script to do as if I was using a shell?

Tags: python, shell

I'm kinda new to python and shell (and programming in  general...)
My problem is, I was given an environment, which is working fine, and I need to activate this environment in order to start a python script.

Doing this manually in the shell (I'm on windows) works perfectly (i.e. activating the environment using "activate myenv", and then starting my script using "python myprog.py".

Now, I would like to do all of that just from a python script. I would like to start a script in my shell which activate my environment in that shell and then start myprog.py

I've check on the internet and found "os.system" and "subprocess.run", but both don't work

myprog.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['activate','myenv'], shell=True)

print('done')
```

This is a short script to activate my environment according to what i found on the internet. Must put shell=True otherwise I have an error : `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Executing myprog.py using the command "python myprog.py" works perfectly, but the environment in my shell isn't activated. But if I write directly in my shell "activate myenv" the environment activates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it only activates env for your subprocess command. The command is created in a child process, not in the main process (where you run your python script).

When this line ends, your child process is terminated:

```
subprocess.run(['activate','myenv'], shell=True)
```

There was an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script) but it's hacky.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I managed to do what I wanted to do by doing subprocess.run('\path\to\env\Scripts\python.exe myscript.py')