# subprocess.call when inside virtualenv leaves the virtual environment on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, virtualenv

I have a local virtualenv (venv) that was activated.

My script executes another script using `subprocess.call()`, but that causes the new script to be executed outside of the virtualenv.

Is there any way to execute another process but keep it inside the virtualenv?

EDIT: I don't it's a duplicate of the given links since I assume it is possible to avoid reactivating the virtualenv, and can somehow "stay within it"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate a virtualenv with a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+subprocess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it possible to use

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "some_script.py", "--param1"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the bin folder of your virtualenv you can find a file named activate_this.py.
You can use it to activate the virtualenv for the current interpreter. Documentation is inside the file.