# How to create Python Virtual environment within a python script

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am required to make use of my local environment and also use a virtual environment for a specific tool but this tool have dependency issues with my local environment.
(I am already aware of how to use a virtualEnv within a script, here I am trying to create a new Virtual Environment within the script.)
I want to create a python virtual Environment within a python program while in runtime(Because I have to delete this env at the end of the program). Need this environment to pass to python subprocess as keyword argument env.

I know I can create a virtualEnv using commands as argument to python subprocess. I am looking for some other approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activate a virtualenv with a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)

Comment: @Nikaidoh No that is for how to use existing virtualEnv, not addressing how to create a new one within the script.

Comment: Why subprocess is not fulfilling your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a virtual env from inside a python script you can use the `virtualenv` python module.

It pretty much comes down to a single line of code.

```
import virtualenv
import os

venv_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".venv")
virtualenv.create_environment(venv_dir)
```

You can then activate this environment by accessing the `activate_this.py` file in your `.venv` folder, and install custom packages using `pip` module.

Comment: Is there any way to install pip packages using virtualenv?

Comment: It should be possible with the `install_wheel` function of this package, which is used internally  - however I have never tested whether it works. You can review the code yourself:
https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv.py

Comment: I believe you can use `subprocess.run` to run the virtualenv's pip. If I'm not mistaken, it should be in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
from venv import create
from os.path import join, expanduser, abspath
from subprocess import run

dir = join(expanduser("~"), "my-venv")
create(dir, with_pip=True)

# where requirements.txt is in same dir as this script
run(["bin/pip", "install", "-r", abspath("requirements.txt")], cwd=dir)
```