# Is there a way to have requirements install dependencies into a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I want to distribute a python script with external requirements, but I don't want to clutter up the users machines.  Can I my script activate a virtual environment, and install its requirements to said VE.

Additionally, is there a way to have the VE destroy itself once the script in finished executing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activate a virtualenv with a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+executable

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to explicitly activate the virtual environment. If the virtual environment is located at `/path-to-venv`, then executing:

```
/path-to-venv/bin/pip install package
```

will install `package` into the virtual environment. Likewise, running the Python interpreter located at `/path-to-venv/bin/python` will cause packages to be loaded from the virtual environment located at `/path-to-venv` without the need for an explicit activation.