# Load Python Packages In Lambda During Runtime

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-venv

I am trying to get Gensim on AWS lambda but after trying all the file reduction techniques (https://github.com/robertpeteuil/build-lambda-layer-python) to try to create layers it still does not fit. So I decided to try to load the packages during runtime of the lambda function as our function is not under a heavy time constraint.

So I first looked at uploaded a venv to S3 and then downloading and activating it from a script following ([Activate a virtualenv with a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)) using the 2nd block of the top rated answer. However, it turned out that the linked script was for python 2 so I looked up the python 3 version (making sure to copy an activiate_this.py from a virtualenv to the normal venv bin since the standard venv package doesn't include one)

```
activator = "/Volumes/SD.Card/Machine_Learning/lambda/bin/activate_this.py"
with open(activator) as f:
    exec(f.read(), {'__file__': activator})

import numpy
```

After running this script to the target venv with numpy I am still getting a no module found error. I cannot find a good resource for how to do this properly. So I guess my question is: what is the best way to load packages during lambda runtime and how does one carry that out?

Comment: I followed this tutorial to build my Lambda layer: https://medium.com/@qtangs/creating-new-aws-lambda-layer-for-python-pandas-library-348b126e9f3e

Comment: ended up just hosting on an EC2 with spare compute.