# How can I activate a venv within a python script

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script which is executed every 5 minutes by the OS.

The problem is it needs to first activate the `jdate` virtual I have created for it in `/tmp` to be able to use the `jdatetime` module installed there.

I have tried both #1 and #2 but no success. Executing the script in the terminal gives me errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# 1:
import os
os.system(f"cd /tmp ; source jdate/bin/activate")
# returns error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdatetime'

# 2:
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(f"cd /tmp ; source jdate/bin/activate", shell=True)
# returns error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdatetime'
```

Comment: Check https://pypi.org/project/venv-run/

Comment: As the name suggest, `subprocess` runs in a subprocess, so it doesn't affect your current process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activate a virtualenv with a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, what the venv activation does is just prepend the venv/bin folder path to the PATH environment variable. If you are using CRON to shedule the execution, have you tried this?:

```
*/5 * * * * (cd /tmp/jdate/bin && python path/to/project/myapp.py)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a wise decision, but I decided to replace ```#!/usr/bin/env python``` with  ```#!<path_to_venv>/bin/python3``` at the beginning of the script.