# Activate virtual environment and run command with single call to subprocess.Popen with shell=False possible?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, virtualenv

Is there any way I can activate my virtual environment and run some process using that environment with a single call to `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=False`?

For example I need to run the following command via subprocess

```
. myvenv/bin/activate && robot myrobotscript.robot,
```

because I want to use the Robot Framework package from my virtual environment. I don't need a secure implementation so setting `shell=True` wasn't a problem for me until I wanted to set a timeout for my process. Calling `subprocess.kill()`, however, doesn't kill the child process and so the timeout is literally useless. That is, because when calling `process.communicate()` with no timeout afterwars the behavior is  the same as if I never passed a timeout to the method at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=activate+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+subprocess

Comment: You don't need to activate the environment, you just need to run `python` from that environment. That is, instead of `. myvenv/bin/activate && robot myrobotscript.robot` run `myvenv/bin/python robot myrobotscript.robot`

Comment: @phd I’ve read through multiple discussions that stated that this is actually not the same because when activating the environment some environment variables will be set which aren’t set when I just run python from the environment. Didn’t find anything about what difference it exactly makes, though.

Comment: The only changed env var is `$PATH`. If you not gonna run `python` or `pip` from you scripts there is no difference if you activate virtual env or use `myvenv/bin/python`. If you gonna run `python` or `pip` you'd better use `sys.executable` instead of relying on `$PATH`.

Comment: @php I am using pip too. I tried `sys.executable` but that is always `usr/bin/python3` for me (also when I run python from the virtual environment). How can I make sure that it points to my virtual environment python?

Comment: Using a bash script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944649/7976758 Run it using single call to `subprocess`; activate the venv in the script and run everything else in it.

Comment: Principally there are only 2 ways to activate a venv: prepend `myvenv/bin` to `PATH` in environment (the modified environment can be passed to `subprocess.Popen()`) or run `myvenv/bin/python` directly. Any solution at the linked dup or in the search results is just a syntactic sugar over these two.

Comment: @phd I've used the `path/to/virtualenv/robot` solution for Robot Framework now, for pip however I am okay with `shell=True` since I don't expect pip to run forever and hence don't need the timeout there. Thanks for your help!