# Activate a python venv with a python script

Tags: python, python-venv

Lets assume a I've a dict of venv and the path to the activate.bat files.

```
    {"env": "C:\\Users\\basic\\Projects\\some\\env\\Scripts\\activate.bat", 

    "test": "C:\\Users\\basic\\python_virtual_envs\\Test\\actiavte.bat"}
```

Now the user is allowed to input the name of the env they want to activate, and I want a function that can activate this venv.

#### The code that I've so far. (That does not work)

```py
import subprocess


def activate_venv(path: str) -> None:
    subpocess.run(path, shell=True)

paths = {"env": "C:\\Users\\basic\\Projects\\some\\env\\Scripts\\activate.bat", 
    
        "test": "C:\\Users\\basic\\python_virtual_envs\\Test\\activate.bat"}

env_name = input("Enter the name of the venv you want to activate: ")
activate_venv(paths[env_name])
```

### Related questions I've found

[Activate a virtualenv with a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)  The OP is exactly what I'm looking for but none answers makes sense, all the answers are targeted in running a `python script` using a venv. I'm not looking for, running a python script using a venv, I just want to activate the venv.

Comment: A venv is just activated in the current shell, right?

Comment: yeah, when i enter the name of the venv it will be activated in the current shell

Comment: Activating a `venv` just sets some variables & modifies others int he current shell. Without a shell, it makes no sense to just activate a venv.

Comment: The first answer in the link you posted should work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66167081/5272038 It suggests using the `activate_this.py `file in the `bin` directory of the venv, instead of using the .bat file

Comment: As a side note. If you are doing this for convenience reasons; like maybe activating using the venv name only instead of having to call the bat file everytime. You might want to look into `virtualenvwrapper`. https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/