# Running command from virtual env in Jenkins pipeline without explicit activation

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, ansible, virtualenv

I use a shell script that, let's assume, I cannot update:

```
#!/bin/bash
ansible-playbook $1
```

The script is called in Jenkins declarative pipeline as:

```
sh "myscript.sh my-playbook.yml"
```

The pipeline runs on Jenkins node where ansible (2.9) is installed in python (2.7) virtual env. `ansible-playbook` is hence not available before the virtual env is activated.

Is it possible to call `ansible-playbook` without activating it in the shell script? I am allowed to do changes on the Jenkins node only.

I tried to create a function in `~/.bashrc` (and source it):

```
function ansible-playbook() {
    source /path/to/my/venv/bin/activate
    command ansible-playbook "$@"
    deactivate
}
```

It works when called in the shell, but Jenkins pipeline fails on `"ansible-playbook: command not found"`. Is it not the correct approach to:

1. activate virtual env, PATH is updated with local virtual env binaries, including `ansible-playbook`
2. use `command` to make bash skip searching for functions and aliases so the function does not call itself in a loop
3. deactivate virtual env

NOTE: sh is linked to bash in my Jenkins node so bash should be executed by the pipeline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541898/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23069201/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+from+script

Comment: Thank you but it requires updating the script which I cannot do because there would be a lot of changes in the infrastructure. I just simplified this case to a single shell script for demonstration. Moreover, not all my ansible Jenkins nodes (of different versions) run in virtual env.