# Activate a virtual environment

Tags: cmd, jupyter-notebook

I usually do the following commands to open my jupyter notebook through an environment:

```
run cmd   
D:  
cd folder\folder\   
.\env\Scripts\activate  
jupyter notebook
```

Can I automate these cmd commands?

Comment: What about some `script.cmd`?

Comment: Three lines in a text file with a `.cmd` extension: ```@CD /D "D:\folder\folder"```,
```@Call "env\Scripts\activate"```, ```@jupyter notebook```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can add your python.exe from your virtual environment to "path" (environment variable), then press Ctrl+Shift+P to open the command palette, and then select this python.exe as python interpreter and as the server to start Jupyter server.

[image: Command palette]

There are other options as well, for example using the execfile() command, or changing the default python interpreter globally:
[As can be seen in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)