# Load venv or add path from python script

Tags: python, path, python-venv, xlwings

I have not found easy to understand answers on how `venv` can be loaded from a python .py script.

I currently have my python libraries installed via PIP on a *venv*. Wish CONDA could be used but it is not the case (see PS:)

To run a script from the Command window (Windows 10) I will do:

```
c:\myEnvFolder\Scripts\activate.bat
python.exe myScript.py
```

This works fine, I can also do the following to run Spyder and then load any of myEnvFolder libraries

```
c:\myEnvFolder\Scripts\activate.bat
Spyder
```

Problem comes when trying to use xlwings. As python is called from excel it points to the stock Python install and does not include myEnvFolder libraries.

I tried adding this to `main.py` that xlwings runs:

```
import sys
import os
home = os.path.expanduser("~")
sys.path = sys.path[:-1]        # Remove default lib path
sys.path.append(home + '\\Dev')
sys.path.append(home + '\\Dev\\lib\\site-packages')
sys.path.append(home + '\\Dev\\lib\\site-packages\win32')
sys.path.append(home + '\\Dev\\lib\\site-packages\win32\lib')
sys.path.append(home + '\\Dev\\lib\\site-packages\Pythonwin')
```

But I then get a error when doing `import xlwings` :

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _win32sysloader: The specified module could not be found.
```

So basically I need to either:

1. Add more info to my current path amending so it replicates what `activate.bat` does or
2. Somehow run `activate.bat` (or similar) when `main.py` is called

Thank!

PS: With CONDA this was trivial. You just pointed to the python.exe on the ENV you wanted to use. With PIP and venv this is not possible

PS2:

I have tried the following: [Activate a virtualenv with a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script)

So I create the `activate_this.py` file and then run:

```
import os
home = os.path.expanduser("~")

activate_this_file = home + '\\Dev\\Scripts\\activate_this.py'

exec(compile(open(activate_this_file, "rb").read(), activate_this_file, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this_file))
```

When I try to do `import xlwins` I get once again:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _win32sysloader: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script

Comment: @rasjani I get the same error message `ImportError: DLL ...` I created the `activate_this.py` file and then executed: `exec(compile(open(activate_this_file, "rb").read(), activate_this_file, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this_file))`