# how can i change my current venv from a python script

Tags: python, linux, python-venv

I'm trying to write a python script that manages my shell context for various projects.
if i run `user@~:source myvenv/bin/activate` it activates `myvenv`. I want to do the same thing from within a python script.

So if I have the python script named `activate_venv`.

then i run `user@~: python activate_venv`
it will be activated and all the python paths change and my PS1 gets set correctly to
`(myvenv)user@~:`

I tried inputting `os.system('source myvenv/bin/activate')` to the `activate_venv` script but it did not work, it needs to apply the changes to the parent process or something like that. I dunno I'm stuck.

I know I could use something an alias or just generally bash but I want this to work within python because this is only a small part of what the project management script will do. Also once I have it figured out `myvenv` will be dynamic.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:
The current virtualenv package creates a bin/activate_this.py script that forces your current python process to use the libraries from your virtual environment

Solution 2:
At the beginning of your script if the invoking python is not the correct one, set up the environment of your virtual environment and then use os.execv to reinvoke the script with the virtual environment's python.

```
import sys
import os
venv_path = '/path/to/your/venv'
desired_python_executable = os.path.join(venv_path, 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != desired_python_executable:
    import shell_source
    activate_path = os.path.join(venv_path, 'bin', 'activate')
    shell_source.source(activate_path, "bash")
    new_argv = [desired_python_executable]
    new_argv.extend(sys.argv)
    os.execv(desired_python_executable, new_argv)
# the rest of your script here.
```

BETTER ANSWER:

Sorry, I thought you were trying to get the venv environment while inside your python script.  If you want to get it in your shell environment that is harder.  There is no way for a child process to change the environment of the parent.  That is why you have to source the bin/activate command rather than execute it.  That way the environment setting commands run in the parent shell.

If you want the environment in a shell, I see two options.

The first is to use os.execv to invoke a shell which you then interact with.

```
import shell_source
# code that dose all of the rest of your project management here
# determine the path to the activate script you want
activate_path = ...
shell_source.source(activate_path, "bash")
os.execv("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash"])
```

You are now in a subprocess of your original shell.  So, exiting takes you back to the parent shell instead of closing the window, which could be viewed as good or bad.

The second is to have your management script's last action be to write out the path to the activate script you want, and then invoke your `management_script.py` as

```
source `python management_script.py`
```

Comment: i'm using `venv` so I don't have a `activate_this.py` file.
`os.execv` seems pretty useful and is heading in the right direction, but I don't think I can use it to change my current shells environment.

Comment: Added a code example that works for me.  I have used the shell_source.source method to incorporate the environment typically generated by sourcing venv/bin/activate into the environment of the running python which then gets passed along to the new process.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come up with that soultion, I've been toying with it a bit. It's such a weird corner case of responsibilities. I've been considering abstracting a bit further in my `.bash_aliases` file `function() management_script { eval $(management_script.py "$@")}`
although maybe the added complexity doesn't justify the flexibility. 
I add a link to some code once I have something concrete