# How can I make one python file run another?

Tags: python

How can I make one python file to run another?

For example I have two *.py files*.  I want one file to be run, and then have it run the other *.py file*.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Also [`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) but modules are usually better.

Comment: also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71311113/16187613), it use's `os.startfile`.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71967141/1364242

Comment: 12 years later, `execfile` has been removed, but a simple alternative is to read the source. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16577427/8387760) and in @apc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975511/8387760)

Answer (score 655, accepted):

There are more than a few ways. I'll list them in order of inverted preference (*i.e.*, best first, worst last):

1. **Treat it like a module:** `import file`. This is good because it's secure, fast, and maintainable. Code gets reused as it's supposed to be done. Most Python libraries run using multiple methods stretched over lots of files. Highly recommended. Note that if your file is called `file.py`, your `import` should *not* include the `.py` extension at the end.
2. **The infamous (and unsafe) [exec](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#exec) command:** Insecure, hacky, usually the wrong answer. Avoid where possible.

   - `execfile('file.py')` in Python 2
   - `exec(open('file.py').read())` in Python 3
3. **Spawn a shell process:** `os.system('python file.py')`. Use when desperate.

Comment: **just to add a bit of detail to case #1**: say you want to import fileB.py into fileA.py. assuming the files are in the same directory, inside fileA you'd write `import fileB`. then, inside fileA, you can call any function inside fileB like so: `fileB.name_of_your_func()`. there's more options and details of course, but this will get you up and running.

Comment: Use `subprocess` module instead of `os` module

Comment: Using import adds namespacing to the functions, e.g. function() becomes filename.function(). To avoid this use "from name import *". This will also run the code body.

Running with os.system() will not keep the defined function (as it was run in another process). execfile is exec() in Python 3, and it doesn't work.

Comment: `execfile` worked :D

Comment: #1 solved my problem and it was SUPER easy! Thank you!

Comment: I was interested in how to define arguments to the other .py script using "import()"

Comment: What if the file is in a subdirectory? What if it has a .py extension? What if the filename has command-operators in it, like "-" ?How should the "import" line look? How should the function-call look?

Comment: Assuming you know what modules are and modules aren't what you want here, `execfile` is the right answer. I see no reason why it's any less secure than importing. You may also want to look at `compile`.

Comment: best first is ordre of preference, or of inverted preference?

Comment: If you need to call a "main" function, case #1 is not so obvious. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14500330/3244382 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/3244382

Comment: Can you give reasons why `execfile` is supposed to be less secure than `import`?

Comment: unc paths can be used with easily with `execfile(...)` you'll just want to use make sure to use forward slashes instead of backslashes.  `execfile('//unc_network_folder/myUNCpythonscript.py')`

Comment: The number one just did not work and gave me invalid syntax

Comment: number 2 doesn't work and says doesn't know exefile

Comment: Number 3 opens the py file in notepad editor

Comment: Are you able to provide more detail on the first solution "Treat it like a module"?  I tried this but am getting a Syntax error when I use "Import File" and the file name.

Comment: Don't think you can do option 1 anymore with Python 3, main() is not always available, like in this case: `AttributeError: module 'sqlacodegen' has no attribute 'main'`

Comment: For ```exec(open('file.py').read())``` how can I pass parameter?

Comment: ~Not sure if I like this as an answer as my python file is in a different directory, and I'm using a piece of structured commerical simulation software running IronPython. How does import #### work when the path is different?

Comment: If you are getting a syntax error, it might be because you are using special characters in the name of the file your are trying to import. For me, the error disappeared when I got rid of all `-` and `_` in the file name and only used letters.

Comment: Will suggestion #1 execute the files asynchronously, meaning, if I do `import file1` and `import file2` will `file2.py` execute once `file1.py` is finished running or will they run at the same time?

Comment: Use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) instead of `"python"` in case multiple pythons are installed.

Answer (score 81):

### Get one python file to run another, using python 2.7.3 and Ubuntu 12.10:

1. Put this in main.py:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import yoursubfile
   ```
2. Put this in yoursubfile.py

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   print("hello")
   ```
3. Run it:

   ```
   python main.py
   ```
4. It prints:

   ```
   hello
   ```

Thus `main.py` runs `yoursubfile.py`

There are 8 ways to answer this question, A more canonical answer is here: [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files/20749411#20749411)

Comment: Make sure that we do not use "." (dot) in the imported python script file name

Comment: Not "import subfile.py" Just "import subfile" despite filename is subfile.py

Comment: Oh please get rid of the semicolon. As a recovering C/C++ programmer it hurts my eyes!

Comment: Agreed, number 2 should be `print("hello")`

Comment: How to pass arguments to yoursubfile.py ?

Comment: Works fine, but you can see a warning because the imported file is not used. With Flake8, you can ignore it: `# noqa: F401`

Comment: @AgnelVishal to pass command-line arguments to the script, you could edit sys.argv list.

Answer (score 49):

I used subprocess.call it's almost same like subprocess.Popen

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "your_file.py"])
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: getting "NameError: name 'python' is not defined"

Comment: @Tahlor add the python.exe directory to your PATH variable in Environment Variables

Comment: @Tahlor, add shell=True

Comment: How do I break the execution of the program if there's an infinite loop like in messaging then?

Comment: Is it possible to send parameter to this call?

Answer (score 33):

- you can run your .py file simply with this code:

---

```
import os 
os.system('python filename.py')
```

note:
   put the file in the same directory of your main python file.

Comment: Does this spawn another process?

Comment: Doesn't always work. -1

Comment: @CristiFati When doesn't it work?

Comment: @Moondra Yes, this method does spawn another process, at least on Windows. On the other hand, importing the file does not. [Tested it by running `tasklist | findstr "python"` in cmd]

Answer (score 18):

```
from subprocess import Popen

Popen('python filename.py')
```

or [how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another-file](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718215917/http://www.thegeeklegacy.com/t/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another/36/)

Comment: Exactly I was looking for. All the other answers

`
import secondary
exec(open('secondary.py').read())
os.system('python secondary.py')
call(["python", "secondary.py"])
`
they don't allow creating multiple instances of the secondary python file at the same time. They all wait for the execution to finish only then you can call that file again. Only Popen allows multiple async calls.

Thanks again.

Comment: Say if there is a `def func1() ` within `filename.py`, then how to just run this particular function only under `Popen('python filename.py')` approach?

Comment: on python3 i needed to use `Popen(['python3', 'filename.py'])`

Comment: I get `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application` with this solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651990/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Answer (score 6):

You could use this script:

```
def run(runfile):
  with open(runfile,"r") as rnf:
    exec(rnf.read())
```

Syntax:

```
run("file.py")
```

Comment: What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Super late response, but it basically takes a file (variable runfile), opens it, reads the contents of it. (contents are read in the rnf.read() function) those contents are then executed as python code, hence the exec() call. Information on exec can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html)

Comment: But what is the logic of doing it in this way instead of simply `exec("file.py")` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975511/1227469)?

Comment: You probably mean execfile("file.py"), and it isn't supported as of Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

You'd treat one of the files as a python module and make the other one import it (just as you import standard python modules). The latter can then refer to objects (including classes and functions) defined in the imported module. The module can also run whatever initialization code it needs. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

It may be called `abc.py` from the main script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import abc
```

`abc.py` may be something like this:

```
print'abc'
```

Comment: I think line: `aa1` is pointless, the file is run when you import it