# In Python, can I call the main() of an imported module?

Tags: python, module, arguments, program-entry-point

In Python I have a **module** myModule.py where I define a few functions and a **main()**, which takes a few command line arguments.

I usually call this main() from a bash script. Now, I would like to put everything into a small **package**, so I thought that maybe I could turn my simple bash script into a Python script and put it in the package.

So, how do I actually **call the main()** function of myModule.py **from the main() function** of MyFormerBashScript.py? Can I even do that? How do I pass any **arguments** to it?

Comment: If you have imported myModule, then you should be able to call `myModule.main()`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm worried by the input arguments, which I usually pass from a shell script.

Comment: Does it make sense to call it with the `subprocess` module?

Comment: I guess it would be easier, yeah.

Comment: The "main" function is just a function, there is *NOTHING* special about it.  It's just convention, at this point, to name this function "main".

Answer (score 161, accepted):

It's just a function. Import it and call it:

```
import myModule

myModule.main()
```

If you need to parse arguments, you have two options:

- Parse them in `main()`, but pass in `sys.argv` as a parameter (all code below in the same module `myModule`):

  ```
  def main(args):
      # parse arguments using optparse or argparse or what have you

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      import sys
      main(sys.argv[1:])
  ```

  Now you can import and call `myModule.main(['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])` from other another module.
- Have `main()` accept parameters that are already parsed (again all code in the `myModule` module):

  ```
  def main(foo, bar, baz='spam'):
      # run with already parsed arguments

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      import sys
      # parse sys.argv[1:] using optparse or argparse or what have you
      main(foovalue, barvalue, **dictofoptions)
  ```

  and import and call `myModule.main(foovalue, barvalue, baz='ham')` elsewhere and passing in python arguments as needed.

The trick here is to detect when your module is being used as a script; when you run a python file as the main script (`python filename.py`) no `import` statement is being used, so python calls that module `"__main__"`. But if that same `filename.py` code is treated as a module (`import filename`), then python uses that as the module name instead. In both cases the variable `__name__` is set, and testing against that tells you how your code was run.

Comment: Sure. But what about the input arguments? I use `argparse`, so when I call the script from a terminal, I do `$ python myModule -a input_a -b input_b --parameterC input_c`. How would it work from within python code? That's what I couldn't find from a simple search.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: expanded to show that you can have it both ways; just pass in the arguments parsed or to-be-parsed.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also specify which excerpt of code belong to which module or script? It looks way more cumbersome than what I thought at the beginning.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: Both excerpts belong together in the same module; I've made that explicit.

Answer (score 59):

Martijen's answer makes sense, but it was missing something crucial that may seem obvious to others but was hard for me to figure out.

In the version where you use argparse, you need to have this line in the main body.

```
args = parser.parse_args(args)
```

Normally when you are using argparse just in a script you just write

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

and parse_args find the arguments from the command line. But in this case the main function does not have access to the command line arguments, so you have to tell argparse what the arguments are.

Here is an example

```
import argparse
import sys

def x(x_center, y_center):
    print "X center:", x_center
    print "Y center:", y_center

def main(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Do something.")
    parser.add_argument("-x", "--xcenter", type=float, default= 2, required=False)
    parser.add_argument("-y", "--ycenter", type=float, default= 4, required=False)
    args = parser.parse_args(args)
    x(args.xcenter, args.ycenter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Assuming you named this mytest.py
To run it you can either do any of these from the command line

```
python ./mytest.py -x 8
python ./mytest.py -x 8 -y 2
python ./mytest.py
```

which returns respectively

```
X center: 8.0
Y center: 4
```

or

```
X center: 8.0
Y center: 2.0
```

or

```
X center: 2
Y center: 4
```

Or if you want to run from another python script you can do

```
import mytest
mytest.main(["-x","7","-y","6"])
```

which returns

```
X center: 7.0
Y center: 6.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - thank you so much for the helpful addendum

Comment: This might have worked with Python 2, but in Python 3 it doesn't work anymore, can't call main() function of a module: `AttributeError: module 'sqlacodegen' has no attribute 'main'`

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper that's due to how `sqlacodegen` is written. It's `main` is in `sqlacodegen.cli` and is written to only parse args from `sys.argv[1:]`. You cannot provide args to `main`.

Answer (score 39):

It depends. If the main code is protected by an `if` as in:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...main code...
```

then no, you can't make Python execute that because you can't influence the automatic variable `__name__`.

But when all the code is in a function, then might be able to. Try

```
import myModule

myModule.main()
```

This works even when the module protects itself with a `__all__`.

`from myModule import *` might not make `main` visible to you, so you really need to import the module itself.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the clarification. I put everything in a main() function, so it should be ok. I'm more concerned about how to pass input arguments to this "second" main. Any easy way to do so?

Comment: Sure: `import sys; module.main(sys.argv);`

Comment: This is a great alternate explanation about accessing `__main__` which helped me, thanks @AaronDigulla

Comment: Here is a trick to call a main from another function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/3244382

Answer (score 6):

The answer I was searching for was answered here: [How to use python argparse with args other than sys.argv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853812/how-to-use-python-argparse-with-args-other-than-sys-argv)

If `main.py` and `parse_args()` is written in this way, then the parsing can be done nicely

```
# main.py
import argparse
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    parser.add_argument('--input', default='my_input.txt')
    return parser

def main(args):
    print(args.input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = parse_args()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Then you can call `main()` and parse arguments with `parser.parse_args(['--input', 'foobar.txt'])` to it in another python script:

```
# temp.py
from main import main, parse_args
parser = parse_args()
args = parser.parse_args([]) # note the square bracket
# to overwrite default, use parser.parse_args(['--input', 'foobar.txt'])
print(args) # Namespace(input='my_input.txt')
main(args)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same need using `argparse` too. 
The thing is `parse_args` function of an `argparse.ArgumentParser` object instance implicitly takes its arguments by default from `sys.args`. The work around, following Martijn line, consists of making that explicit, so you can change the arguments you pass to `parse_args` as desire.

```
def main(args):
    # some stuff
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # some other stuff
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args(args)
    # more stuff with the args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The key point is passing args to `parse_args` function.
Later, to use the main, you just do as Martijn tell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to pass the command line arguments as well.

```
import sys
import myModule


def main():
    # this will just pass all of the system arguments as is
    myModule.main(*sys.argv)

    # all the argv but the script name
    myModule.main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually using `argparse` instead of `sys.argv`. How would it change in this case? Also, from the outer script I just want to pass a few input arguments the user types in, while other input arguments for the inner script (myModule.py) are hardcoded by me.

Comment: Without seeing the code itself it's hard to answer specifics.  In general, you would just pass whatever arguments.  The `*` unpacks an array `f(a) => f([1,2,3])` vs `f(*a) => f(1,2,3)`  You could just as easily do `myModule.main(sys.argv[1], "other value", 39)` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem and I couldn't call a files `Main()` method because it was decorated with these click options, eg:

```
# @click.command()
# @click.option('--username', '-u', help="Username to use for authentication.")
```

When I removed these decorations/attributes I could call the Main() method successfully from another file.

```
from PyFileNameInSameDirectory import main as task
task()
```