# How to use python argparse with args other than sys.argv?

Tags: python, argparse, argv

Is there a way to use argparse with any list of strings, instead of only with `sys.argv`?

Here's my problem: I have a program which looks something like this:

```
# This file is program1.py
import argparse

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Do some argument parsing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

This works fine when this program is called straight from the command line. However, I have another python script which runs batch versions of this script with different commandline arguments, which I'm using like this:

```
import program1

arguments = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
program1.main(arguments)
```

I still want to be able to parse the arguments, but argparse automatically defaults to using `sys.argv` instead of the arguments that I give it. Is there a way to pass in the argument list instead of using `sys.argv`?

Comment: [becouse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments) [allmost](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments) [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars) [do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-default) [not](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#allow_abbrev) [use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass a list of strings to `parse_args`:

```
parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'FOO'])
```

Answer (score 12):

Just change the script to default to `sys.argv[1:]` and parse arguments omitting the first one (which is the name of the invoked command)

```
import argparse,sys

def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--level", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or, if you cannot omit the first argument:

```
import argparse,sys

def main(args=None):
    # if None passed, uses sys.argv[1:], else use custom args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--level", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args(args)

    # Do some argument parsing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Last one: if you cannot change the called program, you can still do something

Let's suppose the program you cannot change is called `argtest.py` (I added a call to print arguments)

Then just change the local `argv` value of the `argtest.sys` module:

```
import argtest
argtest.sys.argv=["dummy","foo","bar"]
argtest.main()
```

output:

```
['dummy', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python argparse now has a parameter `nargs` for `add_argument` (https://docs.python/3/library/argparse.html).

It allows us to have as many arguments as we want for a named parameter (here, `alist`)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--alist", nargs="*")
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.alist)
```

All command line values that follow `--alist` are added to a list.

Example:

```
$ python3 argparse-01.py --alist fred barney pebbles "bamm bamm"
['fred', 'barney', 'pebbles', 'bamm bamm']
```

As you see, it is allowed to quote the arguments, but not necessary unless you need to protect a space.