# How to pass argparse args to python script that was imported

Tags: python, argparse

Say that I have a python script which can take in args

```
# testt.py
import argparse

def main(args):

    print(args.foo)
    print(args.bar)
    print(args.nee)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test argument parser')

    parser.add_argument('-foo', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-bar', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-nee', type=bool)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
```

But instead of running it from the command line, I want to run it from another Python program

```
import testt
```

How could I pass in the arg parameters?

Comment: Your `def main():` and `main(args)` conflict.  Make up your mind.  Is `args` supposed to a function argument, or a module global?

Comment: sorry, just fixed to `def main(args)`

Comment: Any object with those 3 attributes will work as a `testt.main(foo)` argument.

Comment: Some times it's cleaner to define `main(foo, bar, nee)`.  Then you can pass values without creating an object with attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a class for the arguments:

```
import testt

class TesttArgs:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, nee):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.nee = nee

testt.main(TesttArgs('foo', 2, False))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could change the main() function in testt.py to do the parsing:

```
# testt.py
import sys
import argparse

def main(args):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test argument parser')

    parser.add_argument('-foo', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-bar', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-nee', type=lambda x: bool(int(x)))
    args = parser.parse_args(args)

    print(args.foo)
    print(args.bar)
    print(args.nee)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Then pass sys.argv[1:] to testt.main(), from whatever program imports testt:

```
# imp.py
import sys
import testt

if __name__ == "__main__":

    testt.main(sys.argv[1:])
```

One advantage is you no longer have to maintain a separate class when/if you change the command-line arguments you want to support.

*This draws heavily from:  [How to use python argparse with args other than sys.argv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853812/how-to-use-python-argparse-with-args-other-than-sys-argv)*