# import python module while passing argparse list

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I have a script called `mymodule.py` that uses argparse. I want to be able to write a script `fakemicro.py` that will be able to import the main module from `mymodule.py` and pass arguments to it.
My code is based around Brian's answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3do2wr/where_to_put_argparse/ and the accepted answer here: [In Python, can I call the main() of an imported module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500183/in-python-can-i-call-the-main-of-an-imported-module)

I keep getting unexpected errors so I hoped that you could help.

Here's the content of `mymodule.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import sys
def parse_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='yeah'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-i', nargs='+',
        help='full path of input directory', required=True
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-o', '-output',
        help='full path of output directory', required=True
    )
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
    return parsed_args


def main(args):
    args = parse_args(args)
    print args.i
    print args.o
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

and here is `fakemicro.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mymodule
import sys
mymodule.main(['-i', sys.argv[1], '-o', sys.argv[2]])
```

I was expecting that this would function as if I had typed:
`mymodule.py -i path/to/1 -o path/to/2` in the command line
but instead my script broke.

```
$ fakemicro.py path/to/2 path/to/3
usage: fakemicro.py [-h] -i I [I ...] -o O
fakemicro.py: error: argument -i is required
```

I thought that `mymodule.py` would have seen that I passed `-i arg1 -o arg2` via 
`mymodule.main(['-i', sys.argv[1], '-o', sys.argv[2]])`

?

here is what the output of `mymodule.py` looks like when run by itself on the command line:

```
$ mymodule.py -i 1 -o 2
['1']
2
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `mymodule` doesn't run by itself, does it?  You aren't using the `args` parameter.

Comment: so sorry,I didn't import sys either. I added args = parse_args(args) and now mymodule.py returns the expected value when run as is. i'll edit my original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
I didn't pass the `args` argument to `parsed_args = parser.parse_args()` . As such, the parser object was using `sys.argv[1:]` as its source, and not whatever was passed as args.
Changing that line to `parsed_args = parser.parse_args(args)` solved the issue.