# running a python file from the ipython notebook using command line in loop

Tags: for-loop, command-line, neural-network, pytorch, hyperparameters

I have built a model that trains using training.py. I want to tune the hyperparameters and run the following script from the notebook in loop by varying the arguments passed.

`python training.py --cuda --emsize 1500 --nhid 1500 --dropout 0.65 --epochs 10`

For eg: If the hyperparameter is dropout, I want to be able to run the script in loop by varying dropout values and plot the graph.

Comment: This is probably what you need to do
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500183/in-python-can-i-call-the-main-of-an-imported-module

Answer (score 0):

You can run a shell command using `!` in an ipython environment as

```
!ls -l
```

If you want to use it with variables,then you can use `{}`.

```
# Supposing you have epochs in e and dropout size in d
!python training.py --cuda --emsize 1500 --nhid 1500 --dropout {d} --epochs {e}
```

You can also capture the output of shell runs in ipython using `!!` instead of `!`. The `!!` magic command returns the output of the command as a list of strings. So, you can do something like

```
files = !! ls - l
```