# Using command-line parameters within Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, jupyter-notebook, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm running a python script within Jupyter notebook and attempting to loop it over a list. However the command line variables are not being recognised as variables, rather being taken as strings. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500183/in-python-can-i-call-the-main-of-an-imported-module) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680647/running-a-python-file-from-the-ipython-notebook-using-command-line-in-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1) seem to be similar to what I want but I have no experience with using argparse so do not know where to start.

My code:

```
import got
retailers = ["handle1", "handle2"]

for retailer in retailers:
    string = "keyword " + "@"+ retailer
    file_name = "keyword_" + retailer
    %run Exporter.py --querysearch string --since 2018-01-01 --maxtweets 50 --output file_name
```

What it looks like when running from command line:

```
python Exporter.py --querysearch "keyword @retailer" --since 2018-01-01 --maxtweets 50 --output "keyword_retailer"
```

The problem is that the script Exporter.py is searching for the term "retailer" and not actually what I want, which is "keyword @Retailer". Same for the output file, which is being saved as "file_name" and not "keyword_retailer".

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

For context if it is needed, I am using [this package](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python).

EDIT:

I have added this to my code however I get the error listed below. I've also attached the module Exporter.py as I can't seem to fix this error.

```
import argparse
import sys
import Exporter 
def main(args):
    # parse arguments using optparse or argparse or what have you
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Do something.")
    parser.add_argument("--querysearch", type=str, default= 2, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--maxtweets", type=int, default= 4, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--output", type=str, default= 4, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--since", type=int, default= 4, required=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])

for retailer in retailers:
    string = "palm oil " + "@"+ retailer
    file_name = "palm_oil_" + retailer
    #print string
    #print file_name
    Exporter.main([string,"2018-01-01", 50, file_name])
```

Error message:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-4731f5aa548f> in <module>()
      4     #print string
      5     #print file_name
----> 6     Exporter.main([string,"2018-01-01", "50", file_name])

/Users/jamesozden/GetOldTweets-python-master/Exporter.pyc in main(argv)
     70                 got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria, receiveBuffer)
     71 
---> 72 
     73         finally:
     74                 outputFile.close()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arg' referenced before assignment
```

I have also tried this style solution with {}'s to denote variables not strings, as per the answer to another question but no success:

```
!python training.py --cuda --emsize 1500 --nhid 1500 --dropout {d} --epochs {e}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description is unclear as to when it's running a script from shell, and when from a `ipython` (or `notebook`) using `%run`, so I'll focus on the `argparse` problems:

First this needs a `parse_args`:

```
def main(argv):
    # parse arguments using optparse or argparse or what have you
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Do something.")
    parser.add_argument("--querysearch", type=str, default= 2, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--maxtweets", type=int, default= 4, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--output", type=str, default= 4, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--since", type=int, default= 4, required=True)

    args = parse_args(argv)
    print(args)     # a good debugging step
    return args   # or do something with them
```

The `argv` parameter will need to look like something it would get via `sys.argv[1:]`

a list like:

```
['--querysearch', "keyword @retailer", 'since', '2018-01-01', ...]
```

I was going to use `split()` on

```
'--querysearch "keyword @retailer" --since 2018-01-01 --maxtweets 50 --output "keyword_retailer"'
```

but it won't handle the embedded space after 'keyword'.  (`lexsplit` can).

If you make all those arguments `required` there's no point in providing `default` parameters.  Conversely, provide the default and drop the required.  And defaults like `4` for arguments with `type=str` are not a good idea.  They work, but could mess up further processing (`args.output` a string or a number?).

Another way to 'bypass' the parser is to define a `Namespace` object:

```
 args = argparse.Namespace(querysearch='foo', maxtweets=4, output='afile', since=4)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just to clarify, I'm running a script "Exporter.py" from a Jupyter notebook, which I usually run from the command line. However I'm still unsure how to actually implement the parsing arguments approach into my code so I can actually loop over the different variables? As in, I am not clear on where or what format I enter my parameters for the search function.