# How to start a python file from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I developed a python 3.6.6 console app that does some actions. Here is the structure I'm using in this **app.py** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading
import time

# My app content
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # all may code is in here
```

Now I need to call this same app in a parent app that does other actions. What do I put in the **parent_app.py** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#some imports...

#the call to the app.py, but how since app.py hasn't got functions in it???
```

Thanks for your help to this basic question... I'm new in Python as you can see ;-)

Comment: Ironically, whether you realised it or not, you put your code in *the* one place where the code is *explicitly prevented* from running when imported as a module because of the condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, can I call the main() of an imported module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500183/in-python-can-i-call-the-main-of-an-imported-module)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having all your content inside the if statement would be a bad idea anyway, at the *very least*, put everything you have inside that into a function and have that function called from inside the if statement.

```
# My app content
def func():
    # all may code is now in here   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

Now you have a function you can import! But really you should start looking at splitting your code into multiple functions and code structure in general

Comment: you should probably add how to use the function in the module (`import module_name` `module_name.func()` etc)

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik - I was going to but the op's second snippet seems to make it clear to me that they already know how to import a function.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function called `main` or whatever u prefer in `app.py`

```
def main():
  ## TODO

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ## Encapsulate all your code inside this main function
  main()
```

In `parent_app.py`, you can import `app.py` and call the function `main` as follow:

```
import app
app.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

parent_app.py

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from script_to_load import app_function,call_method

#if you just wanted app_functions
app_function()
#if you wanted to be script get executed as it is going to execute on app.py run 
call_method()
```

app.py

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def app_method():
    #do somthing

def call_method():
    app_method()
    print("not with if __name__ == '__main__ '")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_method()   
    print("with if __name__ == '__main__'")
```

as we know Every module in Python has a special attribute called **name**. The value of **name**  attribute is set to '**main**'  when module run as main program. Otherwise, the value of **name**  is set to contain the name of the module.
I hope it will works for you

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on how **if __name__ == "__main__":** works. I was wondering about the reason of this code... So I guess you can have different behaviors if the app is called as **script** or as a **module** of an other app..

Answer (score 0):

just use the `import` functionality and the name of the file

```
from app import *
```

Here the `*` signifies that all contents from the file is imported.

If you want to import only one function or class from the python file, consider doing

```
from app import function_name
```

or

```
from app import class_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may also want to look into creating a class!

app.py:

`class Example(parameters):
//insert code here`

parent.py:

`from app import Example
//use (instantiate) the class`

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of doing this -

1. You can import the file in the parent file.

   import app
2. Using the exec function.

   exec('app.py')
3. Making use of os.system(filename)

   import os

   os.system('app.py')